# JFormattedTextField using a regular expression formatter?

Tags: java, regex, time, jformattedtextfield

After much frustration with getting a JFormattedTextField to work with my custom formats, I was wondering if there was a `Formatter` or `FormatterFactory` that uses regular expressions?

My idea is that if there is one, then I could wrap it in a static class and invoke it like so:

```
mFormattedTextField.setFormatterFactory(
    SomeStaticClass.getRegexFormatFactory("^(\\d{1,}h)(\\s([0-5])?[0-9]m)?$"));
```

---

See my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234726/jformattedtextfield-input-time-duration-value) for more background:
**"** I want to use a JFormattedTextField to allow the user to input time duration values into a form. Sample valid values are: `2h 30m` `72h 15m` `6h` `0h`**"**

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234726/jformattedtextfield-input-time-duration-value/2241997#2241997

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read [this article](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/reftf/)?  In case that link rots away, it says all you really need to do override AbstractFormatter's `stringToValue` method, like this:

```
public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
    Pattern pattern = getPattern();

    if (pattern != null) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            return super.stringToValue(text);
        }
        throw new ParseException("Pattern did not match", 0);
    }
    return text;
}
```

Actually, a quick search yields several fully-implemented, free solutions; were none of those sufficient to your needs?