# Need custom JTextField for currency

Tags: java, formatting, jtextfield

I have people entering a lot of currency amounts in form, so pressing one key less is important.

I would like to avoid pressing the decimal separator when entering currency ammount.  I need a subclass of JTextField that will automatically show decimal and thousand separators while entering number.  Is out there something already developed for instant use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JFormattedTextField http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html,

Comment: yes... still no option for MaskFormatter to be hardcoded into text input area so user can't change it, only see it and browse around  like it is JLabel, for instance..

Comment: You could override the setFormatter method so it doesn't actually change anything (after you set it once), or you could create a wrapper around JTextField that delegates all of its method calls to the underlying JTextField but doesn't have a setter method.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an [`InputVerifier`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) that can enforce any rules you want. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234726/jformattedtextfield-input-time-duration-value/2241997#2241997) shows a simple currency format and a data/time verifier that accepts multiple formats. You can adapt it to accept the default format and interpret a missing decimal separator as a value in cents.