# How do I write a custom JSON deserializer for Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I have a Java class, User:

```
public class User
{
    int id;
    String name;
    Timestamp updateDate;
}
```

And I receive a JSON list containing user objects from a webservice:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Jonas","update_date":"1300962900226"},
{"id":5,"name":"Test","date_date":"1304782298024"}]
```

I have tried to write a custom deserializer:

```
@Override
public User deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
                        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        return new User(
            json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsInt(),
            json.getAsString(),
            json.getAsInt(),
            (Timestamp)context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonPrimitive(),
            Timestamp.class));
}
```

But my deserializer doesn't work. How can I write a custom JSON deserializer for Gson?

Comment: Does this example help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845822/gson-deserializing-key-value-to-custom-object

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? What's the issue?

Comment: Should "date_date" be "update_date"?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
@Override
public User deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    JsonObject jobject = json.getAsJsonObject();

    return new User(
            jobject.get("id").getAsInt(), 
            jobject.get("name").getAsString(), 
            new Timestamp(jobject.get("update_date").getAsLong()));
}
```

I'm assuming User class has the appropriate constructor.

Comment: This approach defeats the whole purpose of GSON.

Comment: I agree, it should rather be `return context.deserialize(json, User.class);`

Answer (score 94):

I'd take a slightly different approach as follows, so as to minimize "manual" parsing in my code, as unnecessarily doing otherwise somewhat defeats the purpose of why I'd use an API like Gson in the first place.

```
// output:
// [User: id=1, name=Jonas, updateDate=2011-03-24 03:35:00.226]
// [User: id=5, name=Test, updateDate=2011-05-07 08:31:38.024]

// using java.sql.Timestamp

public class Foo
{
  static String jsonInput = 
    "[" +
      "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Jonas\",\"update_date\":\"1300962900226\"}," +
      "{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"Test\",\"update_date\":\"1304782298024\"}" +
    "]";

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Timestamp.class, new TimestampDeserializer());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    User[] users = gson.fromJson(jsonInput, User[].class);
    for (User user : users)
    {
      System.out.println(user);
    }
  }
}

class User
{
  int id;
  String name;
  Timestamp updateDate;

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format(
      "[User: id=%1$d, name=%2$s, updateDate=%3$s]",
      id, name, updateDate);
  }
}

class TimestampDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Timestamp>
{
  @Override
  public Timestamp deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException
  {
    long time = Long.parseLong(json.getAsString());
    return new Timestamp(time);
  }
}
```

(This assumes that "date_date" should be "update_date", in the original question.)

Comment: I definitely prefer this model - if Timestamp is the only thing failing to parse, better to make Timestamp deserializable, rather than manually parse the whole User object, when Gson is already perfectly capable of doing so.

Comment: small edit. we can use "return new Timestamp(json.getAsLong());" instead of "long time = Long.parseLong(json.getAsString());
    return new Timestamp(time);"

Comment: You can also method-chain the `GsonBuilder`, improving readability.

Comment: Is there any method to know the ***field name*** that is processing currently in ***Deserializer***?

Comment: excellent answer...it solved my problem perfectly....thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

Today I was looking for this thing as my class had `java.time.Instant` and the default gson could not deserialize it. My POJOs look like this:

```kotlin
open class RewardResult(
  @SerializedName("id")
  var id: Int,
  @SerializedName("title")
  var title: String?,
  @SerializedName("details")
  var details: String?,
  @SerializedName("image")
  var image: String?,
  @SerializedName("start_time")
  var startTimeUtcZulu: Instant?,   // Unit: Utc / Zulu. Unit is very important
  @SerializedName("end_time")
  var endTimeUtcZulu: Instant?,
  @SerializedName("unlock_expiry")
  var unlockExpiryTimeUtcZulu: Instant?,
  @SerializedName("target")
  var target: Int,
  @SerializedName("reward")
  var rewardItem: RewardItem
);

data class RewardItem(
  @SerializedName("type")
  var type: String?,
  @SerializedName("item_id")
  var itemId: Int,
  @SerializedName("amount")
  var amount: Int
)
```

Then for `Instant` variables, I parse the json's time variables and convert string to Instant. For integer , string, etc I use `jsonObject.get("id").asInt` etc. For other pojo, I use the default deserializer like this:

```kotlin
val rewardItem: RewardItem = context!!.deserialize(rewardJsonElement,
        RewardItem::class.java);
```

So the corresponding custom deserializer looks like this:

```kotlin
  val customDeserializer: JsonDeserializer<RewardResult> = object : JsonDeserializer<RewardResult> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): RewardResult {
      val jsonObject: JsonObject = json!!.asJsonObject;

      val startTimeString: String? = jsonObject.get("start_time")?.asString;
      var startTimeUtcZulu: Instant? = createTimeInstant(startTimeString);


      val endTimeString: String? = jsonObject.get("end_time")?.asString;
      var endTimeUtcZulu: Instant? = createTimeInstant(endTimeString);

      val unlockExpiryStr: String? = jsonObject.get("unlock_expiry")?.asString;
      var unlockExpiryUtcZulu: Instant? = createTimeInstant(unlockExpiryStr);

      val rewardJsonElement: JsonElement = jsonObject.get("reward");
      val rewardItem: ridmik.one.modal.reward.RewardItem = context!!.deserialize(rewardJsonElement,
          ridmik.one.modal.reward.RewardItem::class.java);  // I suppose this line means use the default jsonDeserializer

      var output: ridmik.one.modal.reward.RewardResult = ridmik.one.modal.reward.RewardResult(
          id = jsonObject.get("id").asInt,
          title = jsonObject.get("title")?.asString,
          details = jsonObject.get("details")?.asString,
          image = jsonObject.get("image")?.asString,
          startTimeUtcZulu = startTimeUtcZulu,
          endTimeUtcZulu = endTimeUtcZulu,
          unlockExpiryTimeUtcZulu = unlockExpiryUtcZulu,
          target = jsonObject.get("target").asInt,
          rewardItem = rewardItem
      );

      Timber.tag(TAG).e("output = "+output);

      return output;
    }

  }
```

Finally, I create my custom gson like this:

```kotlin
 val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder();
 gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(RewardResult::class.javaObjectType,
          this.customJsonDeserializer);
      val customGson: Gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```