# Is it possible to deserialize JSON property names with periods as a nested object using GSON?

Tags: java, gson

This is an example of the kind JSON I'm trying to consume using GSON:

```json
{
    "person": {
        "name": "Philip"
        "father.name": "Yancy"
    }
}
```

I was wondering if it were possible to deserialize this JSON into the following structure:

```java
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private Father father; 
}

public class Father
{
    private String name;
}
```

So that:

```java
p.name == "Philip"
p.father.name == "Yancy"
```

Currently I am using `@SerializedName` to obtain property names containing a period, e.g.:

```java
public class Person
{
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("father.name")
    private String fathersName; 
}
```

However, that's not ideal.

From looking at the documentation it doesn't appear to be immediately possible but there may be something I have missed - I'm new to using GSON.

Unfortunately I cannot change the JSON I'm consuming and I'm reluctant to switch to another JSON parsing library.

Comment: I don't know GSON well enough, but perhaps it has it's own Parser interface you can implement which gives you access to json key/values with which you can choose to do whatever you like eg. create `Person` and `Father` objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand you can't do it in a *direct* way, because Gson will understand `father.name` as a single field.

You need to write your own **Custom Deserializer**. See Gson user's guide instructions [**here**](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer).

I've never tried it, but it doesn't seem to be too difficult. This [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson) could be also helpful.

Taking a look at Gson's user guide and the code in that post, you'll need something like this:

```
private class PersonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Person> {

  @Override
  public Person deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    JsonObject jobject = (JsonObject) json;

    Father father = new Father(jobject.get("father.name").getAsString());

    return new Person(jobject.get("name").getAsString(), father);
  }  
}
```

Assuming that you have suitable constructors...

And then:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Person.class, new PersonDeserializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Person person = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Person.class);
```

And Gson will call your deserializer in order to deserialize the JSON into a `Person` object.

*Note: I didn't try this code, but it should be like this or something very similar.*

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do this with just Gson. I need a new library 'JsonPath'. I used Jackson's ObjectMapper to convert the object to string but you can easily use Gson for this.

```
public static String getProperty(Object obj, String prop) {
    try {
        return JsonPath.read(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj), prop).toString();
    } catch (JsonProcessingException|PathNotFoundException ex) {
        return "";
    }
}

// 2 dependencies needed:
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path



// usage:
String motherName = getProperty(new Person(), "family.mother.name");


// The Jackson can be easily replaced with Gson:
new Gson().toJson(obj)
```