# JSON tag returns empty array [] while gson expects a string

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

I am using GSON Library to parse my JSON tag.

some of the tags are expected to hold string values (not arrays). the problem is, sometimes the element is empty [] and when it does that the console gives me this error

```
expected String but was BEGIIN ARRAY.
```

The following is the ideal case for my JSON

```
   {
     "internet": "600.00",
    "internet_remarks": "Fibre 1gbps",
    }
```

but sometimes it becomes

```
        {
        "internet": "600.00",
        "internet_remarks": [],
        }
```

My parsing code is as follows:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
MainContainer mainContainer = gson.fromJson(obj, MainContainer.class);
```

while in my class is as follows the varailbas are defined as follows

```
private String internet;
private String internet_remarks;
```

My question is what changes should i make so that the variable accommodate the empty array []

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't control the source of the (poorly designed) JSON and can't fix it, then you're going to need to write a custom deserializer that constructs your `MainContainer` object.

See: [How do I write a custom deserializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson) here on SO and/or the information in the [Gson User's guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization)

If the only time that field is an array type is when it's an empty array, the easiest approach I can think of is simply inspecting the returned JSON and if it's an array, remove it. Then deserialize to your `MainContainer`. Gson silently ignores any missing elements in the JSON and `internet_remarks` will be `null` in your `MainContainer`.

```
class MyDeserialier implements JsonDeserializer<MainContainer>
{
    @Override
    public MainContainer deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, 
                                     JsonDeserializationContext jdc) 
                                      throws JsonParseException
    {
        JsonObject obj = je.getAsJsonObject();
        if (obj.get("internet_remarks").isJsonArray())
        {
            obj.remove("internet_remarks");
        }

        return new Gson().fromJson(obj, MainContainer.class):
    }
}
```

If that's not actually the case and that array might not be empty, you'll need to add the logic to deal with that and convert it to a `String` if that's what you really want.

Comment: Yeah the only time the field is an array is when it is empty. I try to detect the "[]" charcter and the string and replace it with "" ...

Comment: The above will do the trick then. It'll just be `null` rather than an empty `String` which IMHO is better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

The gson parser is confused when you are asking it to parse an array into string.

So, you can change the internet_remarks into an array of string.

Its always a safe approach to use annonations in the container class.

Extras:

When ever you are working with json, these two tools will be handy.

1.[OnlineJsonEditor.](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)

2.[JsonGen](http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/)

Comment: yes. I tried to do that, but then when the tag contins string ..

it gives me this error

expected BEGIIN ARRAY but was String

Comment: You can change the response to be always array.

Comment: How would one do that? should I do that at the class. any sample code will be helpful

Comment: There is inconsistencies with your json code. Please check that. And from where are you getting your json?

Comment: Humm. so you are suggesting that I should make sure that my JSON have a single type?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest declare your second attribute as an array. i.e.

```
private String[] internet_remarks;
```

When you have a single string, still put it in the array.
eg:

```
{
     "internet": "600.00",
     "internet_remarks": ["Fibre 1gbps"]
    }
```

When it's empty,

```
 {
     "internet": "600.00",
     "internet_remarks": []
    }
```

So your `json` will always be consistent.

Also, I noted that you're not really making use of the `GsonBuilder`. You could just create the `Gson` instance with a constructor than a builder.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Comment: yup, but i don't have control over the JSON. Is there anyway where i could change the data type that i get before assigning it to my attribute?

Comment: That's a really badly designed `json` object then! :P Hmmm, I'm still pondering about how to make it work without changing the `json`