# Deserialization of Json string to complex Java Object

Tags: java, json, deserialization, gson

I have such structure of object:

```
class A {
    List<B> bees;
}

class B {
    String с;
}
```

I'm using Gson parser which serializes such object into this string:

```
{"a":{"bees":[{"с":"text"}]}}
```

(with adding a root element "a")

API's format is a little bit different:

```
{"a":{"bees":[{"b":{"с":"text"}}]}}
```

I need to be able to parse such strings into A objects correctly.

By default B object (as a part of A) becomes not null, but empty (all fields are null) which is understandable, cause parser doesn't find any field "b" in it (when it is actually a class name).

I'm looking for a general solution for that, I have a lot of such complex objects and I don't want to implement many custom deserializers for each of them.

Gson is not obligatory, I can use another lib if it's necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer Jackson Tree Model and JDK 8 Stream to parse such json string, the core idea is to map the `bees` array element `{"b":{"с":"text"}}` to `{"с":"text"}` by the functional `map()` API.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode beesNode = mapper.readTree(jsonString).get("a").get("bees");
List<JsonNode> bs = StreamSupport.stream(beesNode.spliterator(), false)
                    .map(bee -> bee.get("b")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to change the class structure then change the class structure so as to match the API's format. For example,

```
class A {
    List<B> bees;
}

class B {
    MyTypeObjB B;
}
class MyTypeObjB {
    String c;
}
```

**EDIT** As per the comments, you can also try to customize `deserialize` method by implementing `JsonDeserializer` interface on your custom class.
You can find detail information how it can be performed on,

- [custom-json-deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson)
- [gson-deserialiser-example](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/)

Comment: Well, I was thinking about it too. But it will increase number of classes in twice. Ideally I want to make it without any changes in bean classes structure (or with annotations or some extra field), to make it with some specific parser changes.

Comment: @a.toropov refer the edited answer and use custom `desrializer` if that can work and you can alter according to your need...