# Some objects can't be deserialized through Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to parse the following url:

http://api.crossref.org/works?rows=2

When I parse it through Gson, I got some records but somehow some others stay `null`.

Here is my code:

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url_tdm.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    int read;
    char[] chars = new char[1024];
    while ((read = in.read(chars)) != -1)
    buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

    String jsonLine = buffer.toString();

    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(jsonLine));
    reader.setLenient(true);  // this is for Malformed json

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_DASHES).create();

    Crossref answer = gson.fromJson(reader, Crossref.class );

    List<Items> ao = answer.message.items;

    public class Crossref {
    public Message message;}

    public class Message {
    public List<Items> items;}

    public class Items {   
    public List<String> containerTitle;
    public List<String> ISSN;
    public String publisher;
    public List<String> title;
    public String DOI;
    public String type;}
```

So as a result of my code above, I can get container-title, publisher and title values. But ISSN and DOIs are null.

I used a `FieldNamingPolicy` because "container-title" contains a dash and I could not name my field like that in java (so I wrote it as camel case `containerTitle`).

I am not sure if this affects **DOI** and **ISSN** records which are upper case or is it something totally different?

Comment: Tried generating a schema at http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org ?

Comment: Thanks @EvanKnowles. By applying first http://jsonschema.net/#/ and after getting schema I used jsonschema2pojo.org and I could run the suggested code. However, i am still curios what was the problem in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix something like this is to use a [gson custom deserializer](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html)

I suggest that you read this other question to see a good exemple: [How do I write a custom JSON deserializer for Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson)

And you can find some other greats exemples and explanations [here](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/)