# Retrofit native crash Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, json, serialization, gson, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit library for communication with server side. From server I get list of objects

```
List<BaseAction>
```

where I store child actions as:`ActionUrl, ActionBell, etc.`
And I got crash in callback sucсess method

```
 Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x610091 in tid 21471
```

***And my question is***: What is wrong and why retrofit crash native?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I spend few hours for debugging and find that problem in List. Retrofit cannot correctly deserialize my JSON and convert it to java object.

In Volley I used my own class `ActionDeserialize<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T>` where I implement class resolving according to class:

```
private Type getTypeForType(BTypes bType) {
    return bType.getResponseClass();
}
```

More details about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6096940/1735347)

So, I resolve my problem with setting new GsonConverter (after [blog](http://naoyamakino.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-configure-custom-gson-object-to.html) reading):

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(BaseActionPOJO.class, new ActionDeserialize<BaseActionPOJO>())
            .create();

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(loglevel)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .setEndpoint(Urls.BASE_URL)
            .setClient(new OkClient())
            .build();
```

And it resolve native crash in native part.
I hope it will save your time.

Answer (score 4):

Add these two lines to your `build.gradle` in the android section:

```
android{
    compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility 1.8
            targetCompatibility 1.8
        }
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I double checked and I had a serialized name that was not matching with the output of the library. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

for me it turned out that i didn't have the internet permission , the error appeared to me in logcat when i switched to an older version of retrofit , and it worked fine with me when i added the permission and switched back to the latest version.
Add this permission to the manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```