# Gson error: JsonSyntaxException when Json has a map

Tags: java, json, scala

I am reading a Json string and make it to an object using scala code:

```
val myInstance = (new Gson()).fromJson(t, classOf[myClass])
```

Everything works fine until I added a hash map in "myClass" class. Then for the following Json input (friends is a hashMap)

```
{"pId":"P:12345","name":"Dan Brown","friends":{"{\"firstname\":\"John\",\"lastname\":\"Smith\"}":1.0}}
```

Then I got the following error at "firstname" attribute as below. Does anyone have any idea? Thank you very much!

```
15/07/29 08:43:05 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 51
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:186)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
```

and here is myClass class:

```
public final class myClass extends implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 11271827L;

    private String pId;
    private String name;
    private List<MyPet> pets = new ArrayList<MyPet>();
    private Map<MyName, Double> friends = new HashMap<MyName, Double>();
       :
   //some getter/setter here
}
```

and here is myName class:

```
public class MyName {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    /**
     * 
     * @return the Json string
     */
    public final String toJsonString() {
        return (new Gson()).toJson(this);
    }

    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        return toJsonString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This `"{\"firstname\":\"John\",\"lastname\":\"Smith\"}"` is a JSON string. What are you trying to deserialize it into? Show us what `myClass` is.

Comment: Note the difference between the `name` field and the `firstname` field. See the backslash before the quotes around `firstname`? It is a string in the json input. My guess is that you are not specifying the type of the map, i.e., `HashMap<String, String>`.

Comment: I have added myClass definition above. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, in myClass:  {\"firstname\":\"John\",\"lastname\":\"Smith\"} is of MyName class in my project, which seems to cause the problem. However, the other one MyPet is a List, which is working fine. Why would List work but Map does not?

Comment: You may have to build a custom deserializer using `GsonBuilder`:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6205384/1011791

Answer (score 0):

in json, key of map should be string. in your case you are using `MyName` as key. so json parser using `MyName#toString()` to convert to string.

My suggestion is correct `MyName#toString()` implementation and provide a static method `MyName valueOf(String)` in MyName class

for example:

```
class MyName{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return firstName+" "+lastName;
    }

    public static MyName valueOf(String str){
        int space = str.lastIndexOf(' ');
        if(space==-1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        MyName myName = new MyName();
        myName.setFirstName(str.subString(0, space));
        myName.setLastName(str.subString(space+1));
        return myName;
    }
}
```

here `valueOf` and `toString` implementations should be compatible.

the above code assumes that there is no space in `lastName`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added MyName class above. It already override the toString method, isn't it enough? Could you please elaborate a little more about "provide a static method MyName valueOf(String) in MyName class" ? Thank you!

Comment: What will a `valueOf` method do? Why do you think so?

Comment: it is java convention to have static method `valueOf(String)` to construct from string representation. for example see `Integer.valueOf(String)`, `Float.valueOf(String)` etc. json parsers use this convention for converting string representation to particular object.

Comment: Things don't just happen magically because of conventions. How is Gson going to use the `valueOf`?

Comment: Thanks all! I am wondering why can't I do the following if my toString() function is already output a Json string: public static MyName valueOf(String str) {
  return (new Gson()).fromJson(str, MyName.class);
 }

Comment: yes. you can do, as long as toString and valueOf complement each other

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is a bad idea. Don't provide complex object structures represented as a String in your JSON names.

Here's a solution nonetheless. Provide and register a custom `JsonDeserializer`

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(MyName.class, new KeyDeserializer()).create();
...
class KeyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyName> {
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public MyName deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return gson.fromJson(json.getAsString(), MyName.class);
    }
}
```

The `JsonElement` will contain the JSON string (it'll be a `JsonPrimitive`). Calling `getAsString` on it will return the Java `String` value

```
{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Smith"}
```

We then use a separate `Gson` instance to deserialize that into a `MyName` instance with the default behavior. We need this second `Gson` instance, because the original one has already registered the `KeyDeserializer` for custom deserialization.