# Custom GSON parsing

Tags: android, json, gson

I have the following pojo:

```
 public class  PageRedirect implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("method") private String method;
@SerializedName("url") private String url;
@SerializedName("parameters") private Parameters parameters;

//@SerializedName("parameters") private String params;
......}
```

The parameters field is changing depends on some parameter with the originating API. So sometimes it is {} "json object" and if it is empty, it is array []. I know this is a fault in the Backend. But I would like to find a quick work around... Instead of parsing the parameters, I just would like to get it as a string as the commented line and then I will process it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your instance of Gson, you can set a custom class deserializer as follows:

```
final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Parameter.class, new ParameterTypeAdapter());
final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

PageRedirect pageRedirect = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, PageRedirect.class);
```

Then you can create your `ParameterTypeAdapter` as follows:

```
public class ParameterTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Parameter> {

@Override
public void write(JsonWriter out, Calendar value) throws IOException {

}

@Override
public Calendar read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    // do your parsing here
}
```

You can find more info on it [here](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson).

EDIT:

If you just want to defer parsing to another moment, you can store your `"parameters"` field as a `JsonElement`:

```
@SerializedName("parameters") private JsonElement parameters;
```

Afterwards, just convert it to String by using `parameters.toString();`

Comment: Thx for help. I have checked these before but "yourJsonString" is coming from another call of a parent pojo... and I do not want to deserialize it. I just need it as a string.

Comment: I see, one work around is to save `@SerializedName("parameters")` as a `JsonElement`. This means it will be stored without any parsing. Afterwards you can just convert it to `String` doing `yourJsonElement.toString()`

Comment: your comment is useful so update your answer to accept :)

Comment: It's not recommended to use `JsonDeserializer` anymore, it's been deprecated in favor of `TypeAdapter`.

Comment: @durron597 good catch, will update the answer to reflect that