# how can I parse json using gson with Json Array of json objects

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

below is my json which I want to parse using json.

```
{  
   "status":{  
      "code":200
   },
   "authKey":"xyz",
   "requireUpdate":false,
   "features":[  
      {  
         "accounting":true
      },
      {  
         "channel":true
      },
      {  
         "skipfornow":false
      },

      {  
         "xyz":false
      },
     {  
         "abc":false 
      }
   ]
}
```

Model class

```
public class LoginResponse
{
    private String authKey;

    private Status status;

    private Features[] features;

    private String requireUpdate;

    public String getAuthKey ()
    {
        return authKey;
    }

    public void setAuthKey (String authKey)
    {
        this.authKey = authKey;
    }

    public Status getStatus ()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus (Status status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Features[] getFeatures ()
    {
        return features;
    }

    public void setFeatures (Features[] features)
    {
        this.features = features;
    }

    public String getRequireUpdate ()
    {
        return requireUpdate;
    }

    public void setRequireUpdate (String requireUpdate)
    {
        this.requireUpdate = requireUpdate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [authKey = "+authKey+", status = "+status+", features = "+features+", requireUpdate = "+requireUpdate+"]";
    }
}



public class Status
{
    private String code;

    public String getCode ()
    {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode (String code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [code = "+code+"]";
    }
}

public class Features
{
    private String accounting;

    public String getAccounting ()
    {
        return accounting;
    }

    public void setAccounting (String accounting)
    {
        this.accounting = accounting;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [accounting = "+accounting+"]";
    }
}
```

As you can see features field in json is a json array, everything is working fine except values in features. From the Feature class I am only getting value for accounting but I want value for channel and skipfornow keys as well , how can I get this. features json Array can have lets say 100 json objects ,

for example features json array has 100 json objects and each json object has different key value pair , it comes from server, some time it may have 50 json objects and some time it may have 100 json objects and each objects have different key

then how should I create the feature model ?.

Comment: using `json` ? You mean `gson` ?

Comment: I would recommend you to use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ which will generate the model class based on the json data you've. @Nagendra

Comment: I have generated the schema using same. You can see its all are pojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `channel` and `skipfornow` in the `Features` class

```
public class Features {
    private String accounting;
    private String channel;
    private String skipfornow;

    //Getters && Setters
    //...
}
```

Can you explain more this sentence ?

> features json Array can have lets say 100 json objects then how should I create the feature model ?.

You mean that you can have other object like `id` or whatever ? If so you have to add all the object possibilies in the Features class. If the json object is present you will have the value, otherwise you will get the default value.

**EDIT**
Maybe you can do someting if you create your own deserializer (this this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074656/gson-mapping-lat-lng-class/33075032#33075032)). Here is an idea (just an idea, I can't test it right now). I hope it will help you.

```
/**
 * New Pojo
 */
public class Features {
    private Set<Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>> entries;

    public void add(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> element) {
        entries.add(element);
    }
}

/**
 * Features deserializer
 */
public class FeaturesDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Features> {
    @Override
    public FeaturesDeserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonArray jarray = json.getAsJsonArray();

        Features features = new Features();

        for(int i=0; i< jarray.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject jobject = jarray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            //Use of entrySet because your object's name are random
            for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> m : jobject.entrySet()) {
                features.add(m);
            }
        }

        return features;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited , can you see again , it still it is not clear please let me know

Comment: Do you know all the possible object you can have ? I mean : is it a finished number ? Or is it just random ?

Comment: Maybe you can create your own deserialiser. See edit.

Comment: Okay . let me try for it

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `Features` with members `accounting,channel,skipfornow`.

And in your `LoginResponse` class use Features with a object **`features`** .

Gson will automatically detect all of these.Object reference name is highly important.

Comment: The problem is suppose a new field added lets say { "abc", "xyz" } then how can parse it in features , You can see I have features class.

Comment: I am using gson first time otherwise I like to write my own parser , and in that I get the key using iterator and gets the value so it is highly scalable , whatever the suggestion you are giving it is not scalable means with every new addition of keys I have to update app