# Deserialize complex JSON using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson, deserialization

Is it possible to deserialize complex JSON using Gson like this

```
{
    item1:"text1"
    item2:{
        item3:"text3"
        item4:"text4"
    }
}
```

To:

```
class MyClass {
    String item1;  //item1 == "text1";
    String item4;  //item4 == "text4";
}
```

Comment: Why would item2 and item3 disapear from the pattern and why would item4 be a direct child of the main object? Can you describe what you want exactly?

Answer (score 2):

The correct models would be:

```
class MyClass {
    String item1;  
    Item2 item2;  
}

class Item2{
    String item3; 
    String item4;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is the full model representing the input but what if `MyClass` cannot be modified ? I believe this is what OP is asking for.

Comment: @Gaël Yeah, after I saw your answer, I thought that that might be the case, that's why I upvoted you. Though I'm gonna leave this answer here in case he/she was actually asking for the models :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change your model, i.e. `MyClass`, you will have to write a custom deserializer.
See [How do I write a custom JSON deserializer for Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson) for example.

In your case, it could be something like this :

```
@Override
public MyClass deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    JsonObject jobject = json.getAsJsonObject();

    String item1 = jobject.get("item1").getAsString();
    String item4 = jobject.get("item2").getAsJsonObject().get("item4").getAsString(); // TODO check for NPE

    return new MyClass(item1, item4);
}
```

**EDIT** : you don't have to deserialize everything manually, if instead of `String`s you have complex objects you can still partially invoke Gson on these objects (as mentionned in the link above).

Answer (score 0):

Parsing out JSON like this shouldn't be too difficult. This is how I would do it.

```
public void parseJSON(JSONObject input) {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(jsonObject);
}

public class MyClass {

    public JSONObject jsonObject;
    public String item1;
    public String item3;
    public String item4;

    public MyClass(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
        parseInput();
    }

    public void parseInput() {
        try {
            item1 = (String) jsonObject.get("item1");
            JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("item2");
            item3 = (String) obj2.get("item3");
            item4 = (String) obj2.get("item4");

            Log.d("OUTPUT", item1+", "+item3+", "+item4);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This article might be helpful..

It has a working example of parsing a complex JSON like this..

{ "pageInfo": { "pageName": "TheTestbook", "pagePic": "content.jpg" }, "posts": [{ "postId": "123456", "postName": "Java Post" }] }

```
     public class JavaJsonSerializer {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{  \"pageInfo\": {     \"pageName\": \"TheTestbook\",      \"pagePic\": \"content.jpg\"    },"
    + " \"posts\": [{       \"postId\": \"123456\",     \"postName\": \"Java Post\" }]}";

     Gson gson = new Gson();
     BlogPost blogPost = gson.fromJson(jsonString, BlogPost.class);
     System.out.println(blogPost);
 }

}
```

You can see the complete example here..
http://howtolearnjava.com/how-to-parse-json-in-java-marshaling-to-java-objects/