# Gson Deserialize:Json Field Name Different from Java Object Field Name

Tags: java, json

One field in the json passed to me is different from the field name of the Java object that I want to deserialize this json into. Suppose I want to deserialize:

```
{"bag": "LV"}
```

into

```
Class MyClass {
    String backpack;
}
```

So the field `backpack` should have value `LV` after deserialization.

The issue is `MyClass` is from a library that I cannot change or add annotations. Nor do I have any control over the json passed to me. I wonder how I can configure Gson to do it. All the other fields match perfectly.

Comment: Seems you will need to write a custom deserializer - luckily, there is a discussion exactly about [How to write a custom JSON deserializer for Gson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson) - give it a shot and let us know if this helps. It does seem like what you are looking for.

Comment: Switch to Jackson and use mixins.

Answer (score 3):

```
class CustomStrategy implements FieldNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public String translateName(Field field) {
        if (field.getName().equals("backpack")) {
            return "bag";
        }
        return field.getName();
    }
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingStrategy(new CustomStrategy()).create();
```