# Create a GSON POJO class for a Complex Json Object?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, json

i am using retrofit with Gson GsonConverterFactory for my API connection. i have trouble to fetch my API.

```
{
    status: 100,
    tb_name: "list",
    data: {
        1: {
            distance: "",
            Busid: "18",
            locid: "6309",
            business_name: " Park",
            category_name: "Activities",
            area: "Sharjah",
            cat_image: "14645915394584643.png",
            cusine: "",
            city: "Sharjah",
            lat_long: "25.342403, 55.379542",
            image: "14650439123004854.jpg",
            is_fav: "No"
        },
        2: {
            distance: "",
            Busid: "56",
            locid: "6311",
            business_name: "Bowling City",
            category_name: "Activities",
            area: "Abu Dhabi",
            cat_image: "14645915394584643.png",
            cusine: "",
            city: "Abu Dhabi",
            lat_long: "24.494183, 54.367608",
            image: "14650440703886102.jpg",
            is_fav: "No"
        },
        3: {
            distance: "",
            Busid: "56",
            locid: "6312",
            business_name: "Bowling City",
            category_name: "Activities",
            area: "Deira, Dubai",
            cat_image: "14645915394584643.png",
            cusine: "",
            city: "Dubai",
            lat_long: "25.251964, 55.332805",
            image: "14650440703886102.jpg",
            is_fav: "No"
        },
        4: {
            distance: "",
            Busid: "56",
            locid: "6310",
            business_name: "Bowling City",
            category_name: "Activities & Leisure",
            area: "Al Ain Mall, Al Ain",
            cat_image: "14645915394584643.png",
            cusine: "",
            city: "Al Ain",
            lat_long: "24.222321, 55.782205",
            image: "14650440703886102.jpg",
            is_fav: "No"
        }

    }
}
```

i created  pojo class

```
public class ktbresponse {
    private String status;
    private String tb_name;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getTb_name() {
        return tb_name;
    }

    public void setTb_name(String tb_name) {
        this.tb_name = tb_name;
    }

    public application.myrestapi.com.myrestapiapplication.model.data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(application.myrestapi.com.myrestapiapplication.model.data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    private data data;
}


public class data {
    private String distance;
    private String Busid;

    public String getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(String distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public String getBusid() {
        return Busid;
    }

    public void setBusid(String busid) {
        Busid = busid;
    }

    public String getLocid() {
        return locid;
    }

    public void setLocid(String locid) {
        this.locid = locid;
    }

    public String getBusiness_name() {
        return business_name;
    }

    public void setBusiness_name(String business_name) {
        this.business_name = business_name;
    }

    private String locid;
    private String business_name;
}
```

But when i try to print

`Log.e("apiResponse",apiResponse.getStatus());`                     `Log.e("apiResponse",apiResponse.getData().getBusiness_name());`

only print status.not working  data. i am first time seeing this type of structure.Let  me know what i did wrong. How to create Pojo class for this structure?

Comment: You have to use List<Data> data not just simple Data object in your `ktbresponse` class.

Comment: @parohy java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 40 path $.data

Comment: your json means you have an object `data`, it has objects `1 ,2 and 3` , i think it may get more objects 5 , 6 ... at the same time it's not an array, which is not the proper way to do it, because in the POJO you will have to have attributes (properties) with names 1 2 3 which is not valid (variable names can't start with numbers) so what i suggest is re-create a new json that will have data[] array, and this way you will be able to use `List<Data> data;` in your POJO, as of now, if you use `List` you will get the exception `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT...`

Comment: How does your rest look like? How did you define the interface? In json do just `"data" : {object}, {object}...` delete those numbers

Comment: P.S: my comment above is in respect of using `GSON` (auto parse) but if you want to manually parse the json response i.e: `jsonObj.getJsonObject("1");` and append objects (1,2,3...) into an array of type ` Data` it's perfectly valid.

Comment: @parohy its not possible to modify.its done long before and done by some one

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to modify the API? If yes, just change the "data" object to be an Array instead of an object with fields "1", "2", "3".
The Json would look like:

```
{
status: 100,
tb_name: "list",
data: [
    {
        distance: "",
        Busid: "18",
        locid: "6309",
        business_name: " Park",
        category_name: "Activities",
        area: "Sharjah",
        cat_image: "14645915394584643.png",
        cusine: "",
        city: "Sharjah",
        lat_long: "25.342403, 55.379542",
        image: "14650439123004854.jpg",
        is_fav: "No"
    },
    {
        distance: "",
        Busid: "56",
        locid: "6311",
        business_name: "Bowling City",
        category_name: "Activities",
        area: "Abu Dhabi",
        cat_image: "14645915394584643.png",
        cusine: "",
        city: "Abu Dhabi",
        lat_long: "24.494183, 54.367608",
        image: "14650440703886102.jpg",
        is_fav: "No"
    },
    {
        distance: "",
        Busid: "56",
        locid: "6312",
        business_name: "Bowling City",
        category_name: "Activities",
        area: "Deira, Dubai",
        cat_image: "14645915394584643.png",
        cusine: "",
        city: "Dubai",
        lat_long: "25.251964, 55.332805",
        image: "14650440703886102.jpg",
        is_fav: "No"
    },
    {
        distance: "",
        Busid: "56",
        locid: "6310",
        business_name: "Bowling City",
        category_name: "Activities & Leisure",
        area: "Al Ain Mall, Al Ain",
        cat_image: "14645915394584643.png",
        cusine: "",
        city: "Al Ain",
        lat_long: "24.222321, 55.782205",
        image: "14650440703886102.jpg",
        is_fav: "No"
    }    
  ]
}
```

and in the model you would just have a List

Comment: its not possible to modify.its done long before and done by some one

Comment: So the second question is if the number of data objects changes. If yes, you can create a pojo like this:
{
  @SerializedName("1")
   Data firstData;
  @SerializedName("2")
   Data secondData;
   ...
}

Comment: If not, that you'd have to create a pretty complex custom deserializer.

Comment: no of object may change..some time array length maximum to 10

Comment: is there any option SerializedName("1")  in loop or something else

Comment: ok well if the number of elements changes than you have to make a deserializer. Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson).

Comment: Let me know more details about deserializer.How to do this with my api

Answer (score 0):

Gson formatter would solve your problem. You can create model from your json template.

Comment: I ve tested out your json template with gsonformat, seems json does not properly formatted.
 [GsonFormat](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7654?pr=androidstudio) link.