# Java class from json with same name

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON object like the following:

```
...
    {
       "url": "checkout.bodenusa.com/en-US"
    },
    {
       "url": [
            ".bonton.com/checkout/",
            ".bonton.com/CheckoutView"
        ]
    }
...
```

How should my Java class look like for Response server.

I try this snippet, but it is incorrect:

```
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private List<String> urlList = null;
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;
```

Comment: this is not valid json : `{"1"}, {"2"}`

Comment: Your data is Invalid JSON variable

Comment: make the URL object as follows: `"url": ["1", "2"]`

Comment: @n00dl3  i't was just sample, i thought you think yourself up. I correct my sample.

Comment: @Phan Sinh The question was not this.

Comment: @Omar Al Halabi The question was not this.

Comment: well this is a bad design, I mean switching from `String` to `String[]` in the json sounds like a terrible idea. You'll need to implement some kind of [`Deserializer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson), I guess. But i'd recommend you to use only string[] if you have the choice.

Comment: @Omar Al Halabi What is wrong with you? I said that this is an example. Json i get from stranger API. JSON correct!

Comment: I think, the first object of your json should be `"url": ["checkout.bodenusa.com/en-US"]`, it should be an array of string like the second object

Comment: can you post the whole json response

Comment: @jemsnaban I also think so, but this is an outsider json. :)

Comment: @Krish https://jsonblob.com/645bfb53-1b76-11e7-a0ba-69bdfe3b2ffb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model like

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class Model {

    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private List<String> url = null;
    @SerializedName("apply")
    @Expose
    private Apply apply;
    @SerializedName("controls")
    @Expose
    private Controls controls;
    @SerializedName("remove")
    @Expose
    private Remove remove;

    public List<String> getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(List<String> url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Apply getApply() {
        return apply;
    }

    public void setApply(Apply apply) {
        this.apply = apply;
    }

    public Controls getControls() {
        return controls;
    }

    public void setControls(Controls controls) {
        this.controls = controls;
    }

    public Remove getRemove() {
        return remove;
    }

    public void setRemove(Remove remove) {
        this.remove = remove;
    }


    public class Controls {

        @SerializedName("promo")
        @Expose
        private String promo;
        @SerializedName("total")
        @Expose
        private String total;
        @SerializedName("orderTotal")
        @Expose
        private String orderTotal;
        @SerializedName("coupon")
        @Expose
        private String coupon;

        public String getPromo() {
            return promo;
        }

        public void setPromo(String promo) {
            this.promo = promo;
        }

        public String getTotal() {
            return total;
        }

        public void setTotal(String total) {
            this.total = total;
        }

        public String getOrderTotal() {
            return orderTotal;
        }

        public void setOrderTotal(String orderTotal) {
            this.orderTotal = orderTotal;
        }

        public String getCoupon() {
            return coupon;
        }

        public void setCoupon(String coupon) {
            this.coupon = coupon;
        }

    }

    public class Remove {

        @SerializedName("type")
        @Expose
        private String type;
        @SerializedName("submit")
        @Expose
        private String submit;
        @SerializedName("timeout")
        @Expose
        private Integer timeout;

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getSubmit() {
            return submit;
        }

        public void setSubmit(String submit) {
            this.submit = submit;
        }

        public Integer getTimeout() {
            return timeout;
        }

        public void setTimeout(Integer timeout) {
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }

    }

    public class Apply {

        @SerializedName("type")
        @Expose
        private String type;
        @SerializedName("submit")
        @Expose
        private String submit;
        @SerializedName("timeout")
        @Expose
        private Integer timeout;

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getSubmit() {
            return submit;
        }

        public void setSubmit(String submit) {
            this.submit = submit;
        }

        public Integer getTimeout() {
            return timeout;
        }

        public void setTimeout(Integer timeout) {
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }

    }

}
```

Use this class along with a Custom TypeAdapter for Gson .Then it will work for both List and Object response .

ArrayAdapter class

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {

        TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = null;
        try {
            if (type.getRawType() == List.class || type.getRawType() == ArrayList.class) {

                typeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(gson,
                        (Class) ((ParameterizedType) type.getType())
                                .getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return typeAdapter;

    }

}
```

ArrayAdapterFactory class

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


class ArrayAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<List<T>> {

    private Class<T> adapterclass;
    private Gson gson;

    public ArrayAdapter(Gson gson, Class<T> adapterclass) {
        this.adapterclass = adapterclass;
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {

        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

        final JsonToken token = reader.peek();
        System.out.println(token);
        // Handling of Scenario 2( Check JavaDoc for the class) :
        if (token == JsonToken.STRING || token == JsonToken.NUMBER ||
                token == JsonToken.BOOLEAN) {
            T inning = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, adapterclass);
            list.add(inning);
        } else if (token == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
            // Handling of Scenario 1(Check JavaDoc for the class) :
            T inning = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, adapterclass);
            list.add(inning);
        } else if (token == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
            reader.beginArray();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                T inning = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, adapterclass);
                list.add(inning);
            }
            reader.endArray();
        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter writer, List<T> value) throws IOException {

    }


}
```

And register the adapter factory like this,

```
Gson gson  = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ArrayAdapterFactory()).create();
```

Comment: One question. I have date deserialize .setDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"). And now i have error com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 4/10/2017, how i can transport deserialize To Date in ArrayAdapter or ArrayAdapterFactory?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Example {

private String url;

public String getUrl() {
return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
this.url = url;
}

}
```

Use this [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate POJO's

Comment: Think again. I get array.

Comment: Go ahead and try your json with the link i have provided.