# Java GSON - make array from String of json

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception, gson

I want to make an array of product objects from a json file which is currently a String.

```
{
  "invoice": {
    "products": {
      "product": [
        {
          "name": "Food",
          "price": "5.00"
        },
        {
          "name": "Drink",
          "price": "2.00"
        }
      ]
    },
    "total": "7.00"
  }
}
```

...

```
String jsonString = readFile(file);
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("product");
```

the line below give me: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
for(JsonElement element: jsonArray) {
  //do stuff
  System.out.println(element);
}
```

some code goes here...

```
product = new Product(name, price);
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
products.add(product);
```

Comment: What is your problem? are you freezing in mapping part?

Comment: System.out.println(jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("product"));

prints null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to traverse the whole JSON string to get to the "product" part.

```
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.get("invoice").getAsJsonObject().get("products").getAsJsonObject().get("product").getAsJsonArray();
```

I would recommend that you create a custom deserializer as described in the second answer to this question: [How do I write a custom JSON deserializer for Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson) This will make it a lot cleaner, and let you handle improper JSON and make it easier in case your JSON ever changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Gson library for this 
You can find the project and the documentation at : https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

try

```
String jsonString = readFile(file);
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject invoice = parser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject products = invoice.getAsJsonObject("products");
JsonArray jsonArray = products.getAsJsonArray("product");
```