# Create Composite primary key from Json in Realm Database

Tags: android, realm

I have two field like store and barcode. I have to create a column which will work as composite primary key and will be the combination of store and barcode.
But the table is being inflated from Json. I want to update the row if the combination already exists.

```
@PrimaryKey
private String CompositePrimaryKey


@SerializedName("barcode")
private String barcode;


public String getStoreCode() {
    return storeCode;
}

public void setStoreCode(String storeCode) {
    this.storeCode = storeCode;
}

@SerializedName("storeCode")
private String storeCode;
```

Not sure how to save the value form Json.

Comment: With a custom deserializer, most likely

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you provide me a sample code so that I can understand it well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6097020/2413303