# How can I use Data Objects instead of a String[][]

Tags: java, rest

I'm calling a RESTful api which gives me the following response:

```
{
    "asks": [
        [
            "219.82",
            "2.19"
        ],
        [
            "219.83",
            "6.05"
        ]
    ],
    "bids": [
        [
            "219.40",
            "17.46"
        ],
        [
            "219.13",
            "53.93"
        ]
    ]
}
```

My data object implementation looks now like this:

```
public class OrderBook implements Serializable {

    /**
     * list containing the price and amount of all bid orders
     */
    private String[][] bids;

    /**
     * list containing the price and amount
     * of all ask orders
     */
    private String[][] asks;
}
```

How can I replace this String[][] with a data object and ensure that GSON can still parse it?

The api is external and I cant there change anything. The result is an array of an array with two properties. Instead of parsing this in java with GSON in a String[][], I'd like to have a Asks and Bids class. The Asks class should contain an array of the object Ask and the object Ask should have two variables: which are value and amount as String. This is what I'd like to have in my java code.

Comment: i don't understand your question, String[][] IS an object in java its no primitive.

Comment: Sorry I added more info to my question. I'd like to have these Objects: Ask, Bid, Entry. But I can't change the api response.

Comment: BTW why do you store numeric values as strings, is there any requirements to do this?

Comment: It's not my api, I can only consume it. :-(

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to change the type of bids from `String[][]` to `Object`.

If you do that, you would have to look into creating a custom deserializer for that class. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson) for details.

But then: don't do that. Why do you want give up on type safety? The quality of your Java source code does **not** improve when you willingly reduce the type information.

Comment: Hi GhostCat. Thanks for your help. I want to have an Ask, Bid, and Entry Object as minimum but I can't change the api. Do you now what I mean?

Comment: No sorry, I don't get your point. It is **better** when your java code understands that bids is an array array of strings. Everything is an object anyway.

Comment: Okay i try to explain it better: The api is external and I cant there change anything. The result is An array of an array with two properties. Instead of parsing this in java with GSON in a String[][], I'd like to Have a Asks and Bids class. The Asks class should contain an Array of the Object Ask and the Object Ask should have two variables: which are value and amount as String. This is what I'd like to have in my java code.

Comment: Dont put more information into comments. Instead enhance your question text!