# Java parse JSON path value to variable

Tags: java, json

I have a problem. I had the following code to parse a JSON string to an object:

```
public AgentStrategy parseJsonToObject(String jsonString) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    AgentStrategy agent = gson.fromJson(jsonString, AgentStrategy.class);    
    return agent;
}
```

But now I have a JSON with values that are not equal to the attribute name. Here is the new JSON:

```
{
   "Market": "USDT",
   "Coin":"BTC",
   "ModuleEnabled":{
      "Patterns":{
         "Buy":"true",
         "Sell":"true"
      },
      "EMA":{
         "Buy":"true",
         "Sell":"false"
      }
   }
}
```

And this is what the class looks like:

```
public class AgentStrategy {

    public String Market;    
    public String Coin;

    public boolean ModuleEnabledBuyEMA;
    public boolean ModuleEnabledSellEMA;
    public boolean ModuleEnabledBuyPatterns;
    public boolean ModuleEnabledSellPatterns;

    public AgentStrategy parseJsonToObject(String jsonString) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        AgentStrategy agent = gson.fromJson(jsonString, AgentStrategy.class);

        return agent;
    }
}
```

Now how can I match the JSON and class as the following:

```
"ModuleEnabled" -> "EMA" -> "Buy" = ModuleEnabledBuyEMA
"ModuleEnabled" -> "EMA" -> "Sell" = ModuleEnabledSellEMA
"ModuleEnabled" -> "Patterns" -> "Buy" = ModuleEnabledBuyPatterns
"ModuleEnabled" -> "Patterns" -> "Sell" = ModuleEnabledSellPatterns
```

Comment: I still haven't solved this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom deserializer in which you use default Gson deserialization and additionally manually parse the "problematic" fields:

```
public class AgentStrategyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<AgentStrategy> {

    @Override
    public AgentStrategy deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        AgentStrategy agent = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, AgentStrategy.class);
        // At this point only Market and Coin attributes are set. Since the booleans can not be parsed they are initialized to false

        JsonObject moduleEnabledJsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("ModuleEnabled").getAsJsonObject();
        boolean moduleEnabledBuyPatterns = moduleEnabledJsonObject.get("Patterns").getAsJsonObject().get("Buy").getAsBoolean();
        boolean moduleEnabledSellPatterns = moduleEnabledJsonObject.get("Patterns").getAsJsonObject().get("Sell").getAsBoolean();
        boolean moduleEnabledBuyEMA = moduleEnabledJsonObject.get("EMA").getAsJsonObject().get("Buy").getAsBoolean();
        boolean moduleEnabledSellEMA = moduleEnabledJsonObject.get("EMA").getAsJsonObject().get("Sell").getAsBoolean();

        agent.setModuleEnabledBuyEMA(moduleEnabledBuyEMA);
        agent.setModuleEnabledSellEMA(moduleEnabledSellEMA);
        agent.setModuleEnabledBuyPatterns(moduleEnabledBuyPatterns);
        agent.setModuleEnabledSellPatterns(moduleEnabledSellPatterns);

        return agent;
    }
}
```

This is how you use the deserializer:

```
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(AgentStrategy.class, new AgentStrategyDeserializer());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    AgentStrategy agentStrategy = gson.fromJson(jsonString, AgentStrategy.class);
```

Comment: I get the error: `Class 'AgentStrategyDeserializer' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'deserialize(JsonParser, DeserializationContext)' in 'JsonDeserializer'`, but when I enter that method, I dont have `jsonElement`?

Comment: Are you implementing com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer? Its method signature is deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext)

Comment: Yes I implement that, but then I get that error on this line: `public class AgentStrategyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<AgentStrategy> {`

It gives me: `Interface expected here`

Comment: Maybe you are mixing Gson and Jackson. The method I see in your error, deserialize(JsonParser, DeserializationContext), is from Jackson deserializing interface. Remove any jackson dependency and add import com.google.gson.*

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it

Comment: Great, so is your question answered?

Comment: Yeah, in 9 hours I can give you the bounty reward!

Answer (score -1):

First option would be to write your own deserializer. See:
[How do I write a custom JSON deserializer for Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson)

Another solution would be to create a class which match your json and than to create a method(from(JsonMatchingClass)) which will transform it into AgentStrategy

Comment: But I have default attributes as well that are getting parsed correctly. Isn't there some way to just parse those elements seperate to the attributes?