# How to parse dynamic json object value with java gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have 2 class

```java
class X {
  public String name;
  public int age;
}
```

```java
class Y {
  public float score;
}
```

The json is like this

```json
{
  "type": "X",
  "data": {
    "name": "myname",
    "age": 20
  }
}
```

or

```json
{
  "type": "Y",
  "data": {
    "score": 10
  }
}
```

How to parse the json with gson but if the type field is `X` then the data will be `X` class instance

Comment: I am not the person who down voted, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't.. i dont have any clue where to start..

Comment: Me neither, but I guess we can easily use `Reflection` (with package as well) to new Instance & setter variable. The thing is we only have an instance with `Object` type which is not really useful in most cases.

Comment: Write a custom deserializer, [How do I write a custom JSON deserializer for Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson) should get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how after some questions to google bard...

```java
public static class CustomTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Object> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Object value) {

    }

    @Override
    public Object read(JsonReader reader) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseReader(reader).getAsJsonObject();

        String type = jsonObject.get("type").getAsString();

        System.out.println(type);

        return switch (type) {
            case "X" -> new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.get("data"), X.class);
            case "Y" -> new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.get("data"), Y.class);
            default -> throw new JsonParseException("Unknown type: " + type);
        };
    }
}
```

Then I use it like this

```java
JsonReader reader = new Gson().newJsonReader(new StringReader("{\"type\":\"X\",\"data\":{\"name\":\"Name\",\"age\":10}}"));

Object output = new CustomTypeAdapter().read(reader);

System.out.println(((X) output).name);
```

But with this i dont know why i extend the `TypeAdapter<Object>`.. i dont think i need it.

Comment: While this might solve your issue (for now), there are several problems with it: `CustomTypeAdapter` creates new `Gson` instances which is inefficient and doesn't inherit settings from your original `Gson` instance, `CustomTypeAdapter.write` being empty (at the very least it should always throw an exception to avoid bugs in the future), having a `TypeAdapter` in the first place (with your current code you could probably directly use the code which is inside `CustomTypeAdapter.read`)

Comment: @Marcono1234 yes i added the code for the write method now and i don't extend `TypeAdapter<Object>` anymore and for the creating new instance every read/write, can i solve it by caching the Gson instance in constructor?

Comment: You can probably apply [@Abra's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77372621); it seems to be pretty identical functionality wise

Answer (score 2):

```java
var m = new TreeMap();
m.put("type", X.class.getSimpleName());
m.put("data", new X("myname", 20));

var gson = new Gson();
var json = gson.toJson(m);
```

if you don't want to create custom adapter then try using map!
it could be one of the most simple solution

Comment: This for write? i think so. i also need for writing anw.. ty

Answer (score 1):

You want to deserialize the JSON according to the value of the *type* element. So you parse the JSON and extract the value of the *type* element. Then you extract the *data* element and use Gson to deserialize it to a Java object.

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class GsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = """
{
  "type": "X",
  "data": {
    "name": "myname",
    "age": 20
  }
}
""";
        JsonElement root = JsonParser.parseString(json);
        JsonObject obj = root.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonElement typeElem = obj.get("type");
        String type = typeElem.getAsString();
        JsonElement dataElem = obj.get("data");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Class<?> theClass;
        if ("X".equals(type)) {
            theClass = X.class;
        }
        else if ("Y".equals(type)) {
            theClass = Y.class;
        }
        else {
            theClass = null;
        }
        if (theClass != null) {
            Object result = gson.fromJson(dataElem, theClass);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code uses [text blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/text-blocks/index.html) that were added in Java 15.

I added a [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method to class `X`:

```java
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s:%d", name, age);
}
```

When I run the above code, I get the following:

```
myname:20
```

Note that one would usually make class `X` and class `Y` [JavaBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-javabean-exactly), i.e. you need to add "getters" and "setters".

Here is a complete code:

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class GsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = """
{
  "type": "Y",
  "data": {
    "score": 10
  }
}
""";
        JsonElement root = JsonParser.parseString(json);
        JsonObject obj = root.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonElement typeElem = obj.get("type");
        String type = typeElem.getAsString();
        JsonElement dataElem = obj.get("data");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Class<?> theClass;
        if ("X".equals(type)) {
            theClass = X.class;
        }
        else if ("Y".equals(type)) {
            theClass = Y.class;
        }
        else {
            theClass = null;
        }
        if (theClass != null) {
            Object result = gson.fromJson(dataElem, theClass);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}

class X {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s:%d", name, age);
    }
}

class Y {
    private float score;

    public float getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(float score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Float.toString(score);
    }
}
```

Refer to [Gson User Guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/UserGuide.md)

Comment: To avoid any confusion though: Gson does not require getter and setter methods, actually it just ignores them and directly accesses the fields. So it only depends on your code style, or how you use the classes `X` and `Y`, whether you want to add getters and setters.