# Gson java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, gson

I'm getting an exception using Gson to deserialize json.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2011-10-19T23:30:00-04:00"
```

The 23:30:00 part does seem strange to me. Is this an invalid date?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GSON deserializing key-value to custom object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845822/gson-deserializing-key-value-to-custom-object)

Comment: Thanks @MattBall! Could you provide an example of how I might plug in custom deserialization when I'm deserializing a class (with nested classes inside), of which one of the fields is this Date object? I'm a bit confused about how to do it.

Comment: The question of how to implement such custom deserialization was covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883615/custom-deserialization-in-gson.  This thread looks like it should be closed.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You have to define the date Format in the GsonBuilder, something like this.

```
Gson gSon=  new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create();
```

Regards!

Comment: your answer keeps on giving.  Was deserializing a .net date in a json string into a java Date field and was getting a parsing exception.  I tripped over your answer here and it solved my problem.  thanks.