# File fields in POJO with json output

Tags: java, pojo

I have a POJO in my application:

```
class Project{
   long id;
   String name;
   File[] images;
   //getter and stter omitted
}
```

And I use the form to add/update the `Project`

```
<form>
  <input name="project.name" .../>
  <input name="project.images[0]  />
  ...
</form>
```

It works well with CRUD operation exception once I want to get the `Project` with json format.

I want to get something like this:

```
{name:"projectname",id:1,images:["http://xx.png","..."]}
```

But I can not since the `images` filed have the type of `File` rather than `String`.

I can add another fields to hold the image url like this:

```
class Project{
   long id;
   String name;
   File[] images;
   String[] imageURLs;
   //getter and stter omitted
}
```

But I am not sure if this is a good idea, since two fields are used to represent the same thing.

I wonder if there is a better alternative solution?

Comment: what is your problem? output json or output the url, If latter then i think using a field for url is not a bad idea, they are different things, the custom url and the original path of image. and if first one then use a library like org.json

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom deserializer for your File[]. See [GSON deserializing key-value to custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845822/gson-deserializing-key-value-to-custom-object) for more details.

Comment: How about if I do not use GSON?

Comment: What Json library are you using?

Comment: In fact I am using a thrid-party library which use their own json implementation to do the deserialization  and serialization job.

Comment: Yes I know that, but what is the name of the library? Decent ones have a way to configure the custom deserialization.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you if you aren't giving me the information that I need...

Comment: No, thank you anyway, I just check the library, and I do not find anything to configure the deseriazation. Maybe I should just add another field.

Comment: Ok cool, if you are sure there is nothing like that then you need a String[] like you said.