# Java Json trouble reading hashmap

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to read this json file:

```
{
  "username": "someusername",
  "password": "12345678",
  "ipAddresses": {
    "2015-09-12": "127.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Using this class to store the info:

```
private final class SavedPlayer {
    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final HashMap<LocalDate, String> ipAddresses;

    private SavedPlayer(
            String username, String password,
            HashMap<LocalDate, String> ipAddresses
    ) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.ipAddresses = ipAddresses;
    }
}
```

And this part of the code throws an exception:

```
private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
SavedPlayer savedPlayer = GSON.fromJson(reader, SavedPlayer.class);
```

This is the thrown exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 5 column 17
```

How can I read this stored HashMap properly?

*Edit: it works fine when i use `<String, String>` instead of `<LocalDate, String>`*

Comment: If you make your HashMap in Java a HashMap<String, String> ipAddresses; does that fix the issue.

Comment: Works fine with <String, String>
How can I still use <LocalDate, String> ? @bhspencer

Comment: @user2997204 Please check this post for [GSON deserializing key-value to custom object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845822/gson-deserializing-key-value-to-custom-object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson allows you to register your own custom serializers and deserializers. This is done by defining two parts:

Json Serialiers: Need to define custom serialization for an object
Json Deserializers: Needed to define custom deserialization for a type
Instance Creators: Not needed if no-args constructor is available or a deserializer is registered

```
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
gson.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new MyDeserializer());
```

registerTypeAdapter call checks if the type adapter implements more than one of these interfaces and register it for all of them.

for more information check [gson-user-guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization)

Here is an example of how to write a custom deserialize for LocalDate

```
public class LocalDateJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {    
      public LocalDate deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
          throws JsonParseException {
        return new LocalDate(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString());
      }
}
```

and use this line for creating GSON.

```
final static Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateJsonDeserializer()).setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

Answer (score 1):

To bind JSON to LocalDate, you either have to write your custom serializer/deserialzer by implementing `JsonDeserializer` and registering with GSON using method `registerTypeAdapter()`, or you can use existing library for that: https://github.com/gkopff/gson-javatime-serialisers

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** You can find [GSON deserializing key-value to custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845822/gson-deserializing-key-value-to-custom-object).

---

I tried the code you pasted with `Gson 2.4` library. Also I converted the `LocalDate` to `String`. It is working absolutely fine.

```
public class SavedPlayer {
  private final String username;
  private final String password;
  private final HashMap<String, String> ipAddresses;

  private SavedPlayer(
      String username, String password,
      HashMap<String, String> ipAddresses
  ) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.ipAddresses = ipAddresses;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    SavedPlayer savedPlayer = GSON.fromJson("{\n" +
        "  \"username\": \"someusername\",\n" +
        "  \"password\": \"12345678\",\n" +
        "  \"ipAddresses\": {\n" +
        "    \"2015-09-12\": \"127.0.0.1\"\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}", SavedPlayer.class);
    System.out.println(savedPlayer.username);
    System.out.println(savedPlayer.password);
    for (Map.Entry entry : savedPlayer.ipAddresses.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + "\tValue: " + entry.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Output:**
someusername
12345678
Key: 2015-09-12 Value: 127.0.0.1