# Unable to parse date value using Jackson and Gson

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, gson

I have a Java Spring REST API that receives a JSON string in the body of a POST request. JSON string is large; it contains multiple nested objects.

Upon receiving the POST request, I am converting the string into a DTO object.

**Problem**

One of the nested object contains a key `startDate` that is not being de-serialized correctly.

Value of the `startDate` object is:

```
"startDate": 1622746800000
```

I have tried de-serializing the string using `Jackson` as well as `Gson` BUT both of them fail to parse the `startDate` correctly.

Exception thrown when using `Gson`:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1622746800000"

If I pass the `startDate` as `null`, everything works fine - string is converted into DTO object correctly.

**Question**

Any idea what could be a possible cause for this problem? How can I fix it?

---

**P.S.** Value for `startDate` is received as part of a response from the backend. I am sending that same response string to the backend in the POST request body.

---

**Code:**

Following is the code that parses the string received in the request's body:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyDTOClass evData = mapper.convertValue(evDataJsonStr, MyDTOClass.class);
```

I have tried with `Gson` as well:

```
Gson mapper = new Gson();
MyDTOClass evData = mapper.fromJson(evDataJsonStr, MyDTOClass.class);
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845822/gson-deserializing-key-value-to-custom-object) is similar but didn't help in my case.

Following image shows the format of `startDate` as shown in the Intellij IDEA's expression evaluator:

[image]

Above value when serialized becomes: `1622746800000` and this is what i am trying to de-serialize.

Comment: How do you parse the date? I assume that that number is the epoch time in milliseconds. Maybe your parser is expecting a specific date format. With the old Java ```Date``` API it would simply be ```new Date(1622746800000)```. Since it is a number and not a String nor parsing should be involved at all.

Comment: What is the format of your date? You can use `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat` annotation to set the expected format.

Comment: @geanakuch added the code i am using to parse the string received from the frontend.

Comment: @akuma8 added an image that shows the format of `startDate`.

Comment: Have a look here https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @akuma8 yes I did. Thank you for sharing the link; I had already read that but the answer below is what I used to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding `Gson` cannot de-serialize epoch time by default. But `Jackson` can.

For Jackson you can do the following,

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyDTOClass evData = mapper.readValue(evDataJsonStr, MyDTOClass.class);
```

*Please note that its ObjectMapper's `readValue` method not `convertValue` method*