# Date formatting and parsing issue

Tags: java, date-format, iso8601

I have checked this site and the web for a solution but with no result.
I have been looking all over the web for a solution to my date format problem.  I have a string that I want to convert into a date format as follows:

yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS

My code is:

```
String myTestString = "20111215-07:26:48.689";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date d = null;
try{
    d = sdf.parse(myTestString);
    System.out.println(d);
}catch(ParseException pe){
   pe.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I get:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Dec 16 15:48:42 GMT 2011"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:54)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375222/java-simpledateformat-for-time-zone-with-a-colon-seperator

Comment: As far as I can tell, the above code snippet cannot possibly give the above result. The unparsable string reported by the error just is not the string declared by your code.

Comment: Ok I have corrected the output.  Please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: I do not see any correction. If you were in fact using the string "20111215-07:26:48.689" then the error would be [Unparseable date: "20111215-07:26:48.689"]. But obviously, the string you are using is not "20111215-07:26:48.689"; it is "Fri Dec 16 15:48:42 GMT 2011" instead. That's what the other guys are also trying to tell you.

Answer (score 2):

**this is just runnin fine. you may not be running the same code :**

[image]

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Dec 16 15:48:42 GMT 2011"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
 at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:54)

Answer (score 1):

i think the code you are executing is out of sync with the code you showed above.  This string "Thu Dec 15 17:51:56 GMT 2011"
 is exactly the value passed into the `parse()` method, so something is messed up in your environment.