# What is the correct pattern for parsing the timezone format with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, timezone, date-format

I want to define a pattern for the Java [SimpleDaterFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse existing strings.

The existing dates look like this: `2011-05-02T13:40:00+02:00`.

I tried with different patterns, but I got ParseExceptions. The problem seems to be the timezone format.

Printing the pattern in Java:

- `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`

  - **`2012-03-14T15:40:44+0100`**
- `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz`

  - **`2012-03-14T15:41:58MEZ`**

But how can I get

- ???

  - `2011-05-02T13:40:00+02:00`

I'm using Java 6, not Java 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can use Java 7 or newer, you can use the `XXX` pattern to get the timezone to look like +02:00:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX
```

Otherwise you might have to manipulate the date string to remove the colon from the timezone before parsing it.

Comment: Thx. Yes the support for ISO 8601 Time zone is realized with Java 7, but my application runs under Java 1.6.

Comment: Maybe you can just remove the colon before passing it to the formatter then?  I think this regex should only have an effect if the colon is there: dateString.replaceFirst("(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)$", "$1$2")

Comment: I can not modify the string first. I use an tool to import a set of data and can only define a pattern.

Comment: Above comment from @matts works for me where I parse a value of ISO8601 date pattern in Android which doesn't support Java 7.

Simple and clear solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit old question, but someone else might benefit from my hint. 
You can use `JodaTime`. As library [documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) stands:

> Zone: 'Z' outputs offset without a colon, 'ZZ' outputs the offset with
>   a colon, 'ZZZ' or more outputs the zone id.

You can use it as well with java 6. You have more examples in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2375539/1676068)