# String to Date in Java

Tags: java, parsing, date

I have a date string like this "**2010-12-10T20:03:53-06:00**"
I want to convert the same into equivalent date object in **Java**.
Any Idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Java 7, you should be okay without any string massaging, using the new `X` specifier for the UTC offset:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", Locale.US);
Date date = format.parse(text);
```

(Testing to make sure - when I've installed JDK 7 myself :)

In general I would *strongly* recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for date handling, however. Its `Z` specifier can handle an offset with a colon:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                                            .withLocale(Locale.US);
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(text);
```

In fact, there's an `ISODateTimeFormat` class to make this even simpler:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
```

Joda Time is a *significantly* better date/time API than the built-in one. (It's far from perfect, but it's a lot better than `Date` and `Calendar`...)

Comment: well will need another help here ...how to convert date object back to this format?

Comment: @Avidev9: Call `format` instead of `parse`. That will pick up the time zone from the `SimpleDateTime` though, so you should consider what you set that to.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is SimpleDateFormat.parse(). It will convert a string into a Date object.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Java 1.4.2 (which you point to) won't be able to parse the `-06:00` with a colon - Java 7+ will.

Comment: interesting. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use DateFormat class for this:

First you need to get rid of that `:`  in the timezone part and make your date string like this

```
2010-12-10T20:03:53-0600
```

and use the code snippet below:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");    
Date d = formatter.parse("2010-12-10T20:03:53-0600");
```

Note: I checked this on Java 6 and Mr. Skeet has mentioned a better answer dealing with Java 7 as I don't know more about Java 7

Answer (score 0):

Use [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). It is powerful and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse a date with a colon in the time zone with the standard JDK Date until Java 7. Before Java 7 timezone would have to be either a full time zone with name or in the form `-0600`.

You have 3 options:

- if you use Java 7+, use this pattern: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"` with a SimpleDateFormat
- manually remove the colon and parse
- use Joda Time, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2375539/829571

Here is an example with the second option:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String input = "2010-12-10T20:03:53-06:00";
    int colon = input.lastIndexOf(":");
    input = input.substring(0, colon) + input.substring(colon + 1, input.length());
    System.out.println(input);
    DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    Date date = fmt.parse(input);
    System.out.println("date = " + date);
}
```

Comment: Hi assylias - Please change `YYYY` to `yyyy`. `Y` specifies `Week year`.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2010-12-10T20:03:53-06:00");
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2010-12-10T20:03:53-06:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/gWRuV5)

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `OffsetDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>