# Android Format date with time zone

Tags: java, android, calendar, google-calendar-api, simpledateformat

I need to format the date into a specific string.

I used `SimpleDateFormat` class to format the date using the pattern "**`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`**" it returns current date as 
"`2013-01-04T15:51:45+0530`" but I need as
"`2013-01-04T15:51:45+05:30`".

Below is the coding used,

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.ENGLISH);      
Log.e(C.TAG, "formatted string: "+sdf.format(c.getTime()));
```

**Output**: formatted string: `2013-01-04T15:51:45+0530`

I need the format as `2013-01-04T15:51:45+05:30` just adding the colon in between gmt time.

Because I'm working on Google calendar to insert an event, it accepts only the required format which I have mentioned.

Comment: I don't think you can with a simpledateformat. So you will need to insert the `:` manually. [Java 7 has introduced the `X` marker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) that has more formatting options than `Z` but it is not available on android (yet?).

Comment: If formatting manually is the task to be done(in reference to the above comment), you can search for the last `+` and then add a `:` after 2 indices.

Comment: @KazekageGaara It could also be a `-`...

Comment: While in 2013 it was reasonable to use `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`, don’t do that anymore. Those classes are poorly designed and now long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Or just `OffsetDateTime.toString` and no formatter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead. Its `DateTimeFormat` has a `ZZ` format attribute which does what you want.

[Link](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

Big advantage: unlike `SimpleDateFormat`, `DateTimeFormatter` is thread safe. Usage:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ")
    .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: I found a slightly different way of doing this, given the: 

DateTime my_date = new DateTime();

... Set the date to something my_date = ...

Then format it with: 

String curr_date = my_date.toLocalDate().toString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: **Update:** The *Joda-Time* framework has been replaced by *java.time* defined in JSR 310. Most of *java.time* functionality is available in all versions of Android with the latest tooling using API "desugaring". See links and more info in [Answer by Live and Let Live](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65708581/642706).

Answer (score 35):

You can also use "ZZZZZ" instead of "Z" in your pattern (according to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)). Something like this

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ", Locale.ENGLISH);      
    Log.e(C.TAG, "formatted string: "+sdf.format(c.getTime()));
```

Comment: This is correct answer, @fargath you should mark it up.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. I find it ridiculous when people refer to libraries as a primary solution instead of it being a secondary suggestion.

It's like threading cloth with a sword.

Comment: The documentation says it supports X.

Comment: For me this doesn't work. I get this string: `2018-07-06T11:46:43+0200`. The colon in the timezone is missing. So it's not ISO8601.

Comment: I fail to see the linked documentation mentioning the possibility of 5 `Z` (`ZZZZZ`). Is that just me? Also on my Java 8 I get `formatted string: 2019-03-21T16:06:30+0100` without colon, but the outcome on Android may be different.

Comment: For me, this doesn't work, I have to use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

You can use the pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` for your desired output.

## *java.time*

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

### Using the modern date-time API:

**Building an object that holds date, time and timezone offset information and formatting the same:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2013, 1, 4), LocalTime.of(15, 51, 45),
                ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(5, 30));

        // Print the default format i.e. the string returned by OffsetDateTime#toString
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dtf.format(odt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2013-01-04T15:51:45+05:30
2013-01-04T15:51:45+05:30
```

As you can notice, the outputs for the default format and for that using a `DateTimeFormatter` are same. However, there is a catch here: the implementation of [`OffsetDateTime#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toString--) **omits** the second and the fraction of second if they are `0` i.e. if the time in the above code is `LocalTime.of(15, 0, 0)`, the output for the default format will be `2013-01-04T15:00+05:30`. If you need a string like `2013-01-04T15:00:00+05:30` for this time, you will have to use a `DateTimeFormatter` with the desired pattern.

**Parsing and formatting:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfForInputString = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2013-01-04T15:51:45+0530", dtfForInputString);

        // Print the default format i.e. the string returned by OffsetDateTime#toString
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtfCustomOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dtfCustomOutput.format(odt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2013-01-04T15:51:45+05:30
2013-01-04T15:51:45+05:30
```

### Using the legacy API:

**Building a date-time object for the given timezone offset and formatting the same:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));
        calendar.set(2013, 0, 4, 15, 51, 45);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2013-01-04T15:51:45+05:30
```

The `Calendar` class uses `UTC` (or `GMT`) as its default timezone and therefore, unless you specify the timezone with it, it will return the `java.util.Date` object for `UTC`.

Similarly, the `SimpleDateFormat` class also uses `UTC` as its default timezone and therefore, unless you specify the timezone with it, it will return the formatted `String` for the corresponding date-time in `UTC`.

**Parsing and formatting:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfForInputString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdfForInputString.parse("2013-01-04T15:51:45+0530");

        SimpleDateFormat sdfCustomOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdfCustomOutput.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));
        System.out.println(sdfCustomOutput.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2013-01-04T15:51:45+05:30
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is just add the ":" manually using substring(). I have faced this earlier and this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.ENGLISH);   

System.out.println("formatted string: "+sdf.format(c.getTime()));

String text = sdf.format(c.getTime());  
String result = text.substring(0, 22) + ":" + text.substring(22);  
System.out.println("result = " + result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it manually with regexp?

```
String oldDate = "2013-01-04T15:51:45+0530";
String newDate = oldDate.replaceAll("(\\+\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)", "$1:$2");
```

Same result, with substring (if performance is an issue).

```
String oldDate = "2013-01-04T15:51:45+0530";
int length = oldDate.length();
String newDate = oldDate.substring(0, length - 2) + ':' + oldDate.substring(length - 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the date for a different timeZone (which the title suggests)

```
  val nowMillsUTC = System.currentTimeMillis()

  val timeZoneID = "Australia/Perth"
  val tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneID)

  val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm  dd.MMM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
  simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(tz)
  val resultTxt = simpleDateFormat.format(nowMillsUTC)

  print(timeZoneID + " -> " + resultTxt)
  //   Australia/Perth -> 19.59  21.Mar.2019
```

Comment: Apart from `SimpleDateFormat` and `TimeZone` being poorly designed and long outdated: On my Java 8 `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()[358]` is `Australia/Yancowinna`, and who knows what it will be in future Java versions? I wouldn’t be too sure about Android either, but haven’t tried.

Comment: you are right - the getAvailableID's is unreliable. I edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
String s = sdf.format(c.getTime());
String fDate = s.substring(0, s.length()-2) +":"+s.substring(s.length()-2, s.length());
Log.e("check", "formatted string: "+fDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it on android Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26

```
int offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
String str_date='20:30 12-01-2021';
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd-MM-yyy",Locale.US);
Date date = formatter.parse(str_date);
long utcTime = date.getTime() + (3600000*3);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
String dateStr = sdf.format(utcTime + offset);
System.out.println(dateStr);
```

As my server sends the time with -3 timezone i have to add (3600*3) to getTime and i save it into utcTime, this way utcTime is in UTC. And then i add to utcTime the offset of the phone current timezone.
In my case as my timezone is -3 its prints:

```
20:30 12/01/2021
```

But if i change my time zone the date also changes.

I already answer it here to:
[Convert UTC into Local Time on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677546/convert-utc-into-local-time-on-android/65687433#65687433)

Answer (score -1):

Simply refactor this code and replace the 'Locale.getDefault()' with the Locale you need

```
private SimpleDateFormat getDateFormat() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = (SimpleDateFormat) SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.SHORT, SimpleDateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.getDefault());
    String pattern = dateFormat.toLocalizedPattern();
    pattern = pattern.trim();
    dateFormat.applyLocalizedPattern(pattern);
    return dateFormat;
}
```

//And here is the usage

SimpleDateFormat sdf = getDateFormat();

sdf.format(new Date());