# How to create android time in JSON Format

Tags: java, android, json, android-date

I want to get the current time and convert it to JSON Format as shown below:

```
'2015-11-02T17:22:04.184+00:00'
```

The Date and DateFormat doesn't appear to have a method to do this.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

EDIT: This is not a duplicate question

The answer suggested does not get me the time and date in this format:

```
'2015-11-02T17:22:04.184+00:00'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTC time into Local TIme in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677546/utc-time-into-local-time-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "JSON Format"?

JSON is just a **string:value** object (this is why people "-1" you). You can read about it [here](http://www.json.org/).

A JSON format would be { "date":"2015-11-02T17:22:04.184+00:00"}

To convert the date string to Java Date object you can use SimpleDateFormat. You can see some examples [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/text/java-dateformat-example/)