# What is the right way to format Time between different timezones?

Tags: java, formatting, timezone, jodatime

I want to format time like 19:19:00 to different time zones. If I use `SimpleDateFormat` it always takes into account the start of the epoch: 1970.01.01.

Some timezones have different offsets on the start of the epoch and now. For example, the default offset from Europe/Kiev now is UTC+0200 but in 1970 it was UTC+0300. That means if I run my server under Europe/Kiev the client which login under Europe/Berlin(UTC+0100) will see three hours different instead of two.

I can solve this problem by writing a custom formatter for `java.sql.Time`. But I want to ask maybe there are some common approach or Java tools/libraries which can solve it.

Another solution can be using joda-time:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Kiev"));
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Kiev"));

DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS")
   .withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"))
   .print(Time.valueOf("19:00:00").getTime());
```

Comment: What about `java.time`, have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't format *just* a time to different time zones. You need a date.

If you want to assume that the date of that time is today, you can try this code:

```
ZoneId originalZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Kiev");
ZoneId targetZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");
LocalTime originalTime = LocalTime.parse("19:19:00");
LocalTime convertedTime = LocalDate.now(originalZone)
                            .atTime(originalTime)
                            .atZone(originalZone)
                            .withZoneSameInstant(targetZone)
                            .toLocalTime();
System.out.println(convertedTime);
```

Comment: Good point that you need to assume a date. Using `java.time`is the obvious good idea. Isn’t your code a bit complicated? I’d do something like `LocalDate.now(originalZone).atTime(LocalTime.parse("19:19:00")).atZone(originalZone).withZoneSameInstant(targetZone).toLocalTime()`.

Comment: I can easily format time as a timestamp because there is date part which know what timezone was on that date. But I want to format time without a date part.

Comment: LocalDate.now(originalZone).atTime(LocalTime.parse("19:19:00")).atZone(originalZone).withZoneSameInstant(targetZone).toLocalTime() will return different result according to Daylight saving dates and rules.

Comment: @OleV.V. Edited.

Comment: @V.Spachynskyi So you _don't_ want to care about DST? Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Is `java.time.instant` an alternative for you? It handles all Timestamps internally as UTC-Time.

One way to parse it from a string is `Instant.parse("2018-05-30T19:00:00")`

If you want to have the time for a specific timezone you can get it with `myInstant.atZone("Zone")`

Answer (score 0):

```
    ZoneId originalZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Kiev");
    ZoneId targetZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");
    LocalDate assumedDate = LocalDate.now(originalZone);
    String formattedTime = assumedDate.atTime(LocalTime.parse("19:19:00"))
            .atZone(originalZone)
            .withZoneSameInstant(targetZone)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
    System.out.println(formattedTime);
```

Today this printed:

> 18:19:00

When you know the date, you should of course use that instead of just today. In the case of Kyiv and Berlin I think they follow the same rules for summer time (DST), so the precise date may not be important. If converting between zones that don’t use the same transitions, or between a time zone that uses summer time and one that doesn’t, it’s suddenly crucial. And who knows in which of those two countries the politicians will change the rules next year? Better be safe.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.