# Convert UTC String to UTC Date [Android - Java]

Tags: java, android, date, utc

I want to convert UTC time to Date. It should return Date as

Expected result is : `2020-09-01T08:44:25.654Z`

output is  -> `"Tue Sep 01 14:14:25 GMT+05:30 2020"`.

I am getting `UTC` but it is in `String` I want the same `format` in `Date datatype`.

I want it as `Date` with the above `UTC` format.

Does anyone know how to get it?

```
public static Date convertToUtcTime(Date date) throws ParseException {
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DateFormats.yyyyMMddThhmmssZ);  //"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"
     sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

     return sdf.parse(sdf.format(date));
}
```

Also i dont want to use toInstant method

[UPDATED]

```
Date strFromDate;
try {
     strFromDate = AppUtils.convertToUtcTime(myCalendar.getTime());
} catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

then passing strFromDate to api request
I am not getting expected result from strFromDate

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677546/convert-utc-into-local-time-on-android#:~:text=String%20dateStr%20%3D%20%22Jul%2016%2C,%22))%3B%20Date%20date%20%3D%20df.

Comment: @UmairMubeen i want the result as UTC format but in Date datatype. I want to send 2020-09-01T08:44:25.654Z this as Date in api request but it's going as "Tue Sep 01 14:14:25 GMT+05:30 2020"

Comment: post your input and your desired output

Comment: input Date - Tue Sep 01 14:14:25 GMT+05:30 2020    Output Date - 2020-09-01T08:44:25.654Z   @UmairMubeen

Comment: you are viewing the date on returned object either using System.out.println or in ide, this view is showing you toString version of date, if you need to display formatted date, you should return String from your method, which is formatted already to your needs.

Comment: @soniKumari i am getting the desired output in string format but i want to pass the output in date format to api. My current request -> Tue Sep 01 14:14:25 GMT+05:30 2020 this is going in Date format I want to send -> 2020-09-01T08:44:25.654Z in Date format

Comment: @ShrutiSuryawanshi   your code is correct and seems to work! you must be wrong somewhere else. show us how you are using returned date object.

Comment: @Omid.N updated the post. please check

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Who is your favourite actor? Let's say it's [Amitabh Bachchan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amitabh_Bachchan). No matter what role he plays, he still remains himself (and that is why directors/producers go to him with next offer ). His acting decorates his look as per the role. What directors get using his acting skill is a decorated character representing him as per the specified role. And, then you say Amitabh Bachchan as an `angry young man` OR Amitabh Bachchan as a `coolie` etc.)

Similarly, no matter what kind of look you ask `java.util.Date` to take (using `SimpleDateFormat`), it always represents the no. of milliseconds from the epoch of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`. It does not have any time-zone or zone-offset information.  From this milliseconds, Java calculates the date and time based on the time-zone of your JVM and then combines the obtained date and time with the time-zone of your JVM and finally returns the string when its `toString()` method is called. I believe you already know that when you print an object using `System.out.println`, the string returned by the object's `toString()` method gets printed. Check [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/util/Date.java) for more details of the `toString()` implementation of `java.util.Date`. A `SimpeDateFormat` changes the look of `java.util.Date` as per the pattern. What you get using a `SimpeDateFormat` is a decorated string representing the `Date` object as per the specified pattern. And, then you say `Date` as a string of `EEE MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm` pattern OR `Date` as a string of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` pattern etc.

**The summary is**: You can not change `Date` object by specifying different patterns. If you print it, you will always get the string returned by its `toString()` function. If you want a different string, you can do so by using `SimpleDateFormat`.

### A recommendation:

I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat` to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (package, `java.time.format`). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

If your Android API level is still not compliant with Java8, check [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project) and [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

Comment: No, what about this line :`I am not getting expected result from strFromDate` ..... I have been trying to do it after seeing this question, but his code does not work it doesn't change the time zone of date obj. He has written that line because his English is bad (like me).  Try it!

Comment: @Omid.N - OP's code compiles successfully. Please try `String strDate = "2020-09-01T08:44:25.654Z";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
  Date date = sdf.parse(strDate);
  sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  System.out.println(sdf.parse(sdf.format(date)));`