# Java: SimpleDateFormat not simplifying to specified pattern?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Tried converting string of yyyy-mm-dd, example 2013-12-30, to date object using SimpleDateFormat.parse("yyyy-mm-dd").

Expected output of 2013-12-30, received output of Mon Dec 30 00:00:00 EST 2013 object.

Tried finding out why SimpleDateFormat is returning a different format, but overwhelmed when trying to look through the java api. Asking for clarifications on what is going on and what would be a better approach.

Note: Stuck using java.utl.Date.

```
    ...
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    dateArray = new Date[rowCount];

    try {
        for(int index = 0; index < rowCount; index++){
            dateArray[index] = simpleDateFormat.parse(fileArray[index][0]);
            System.out.println(dateArray[index].toString());
        }
    } catch(ParseException err){
        System.out.println("ERR: Data parse exception. Format is not correct.");
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: If I may ask, why are you using the old `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` classes?

Comment: Instead of printing the `Date` directly, use your `SimpleDateFormat` (`format()` method) to get a string in that same format.

Comment: The format is separate from a `Date` object. Use `simpleDateFormat.format(dateArray[index]);`.

Comment: @MCEmperor: Taking an outdated college course on java. Lessons are updated, but not the Assignments. Only a few assignments have one has one or two specifications using deprecated packages. In this case it would be the Date class.

Comment: @Kayaman: Thank you for the clear explanation. I have a better understanding of how SimpleDataFormat works as well as slowing piecing together what I have been reading. I really should be building a print method in this case. Thank you.

Comment: Not necessarily, if you have that formatter as a local variable there. Might as well inline it, if you just want to print it.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern, `mm` stands for **minute**, not **month**. For **month**, you need to use `MM`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String strDate = "2013-12-30";
        SimpleDateFormat sdfISO8601 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = sdfISO8601.parse(strDate);
        System.out.println(date);

        String strDateISO8601 = sdfISO8601.format(date);
        System.out.println(strDateISO8601);

        // Some other format
        String strSomeOtherFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMM dd yyyy").format(date);
        System.out.println(strSomeOtherFormat);
    }
}
```

I also recommend you check [Convert UTC String to UTC Date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63870230/10819573).

Note that the date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. I suggest you should stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

**Using the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "2013-12-30";
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDate);
        System.out.println(date);

        String strDate8601 = date.toString();
        System.out.println(strDate8601);

        // Custom format
        String customFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE MMM dd uuuu").format(date);
        System.out.println(customFormat);
    }
}
```

Your date string is already in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for date and therefore do not need to use any formatter to parse it when you use the modern date-time API.

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: @OleV.V. - I hope you are doing well. The first sentence `Tried converting string of yyyy-mm-dd, example 2013-12-30, to date object using SimpleDateFormat.parse("yyyy-mm-dd").` of the question is the real culprit .