# How to get date format with timezone in java

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, datetime-format, date-formatting

I'm new to java. I'd like to get this date format with the timezone in text at the end there.

```
2017-11-23T23:43:45-05:00[America/New_York]
```

What I have is this for now, I'd also like to add the user's default timezone as the timezone at the end there. Here's what I currently have:

```
SimpleDateFormat trust = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());
```

Which gives me (Example):

```
2018-08-17T22:39:39-0400
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157476/android-format-date-with-time-zone

Comment: @ADM That answer is over 5 years old and recommends Joda Time.  All the functionality of Joda Time has been in the standard Java library for quite some time now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Format date with time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157476/android-format-date-with-time-zone)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @jsDevia That Question you linked is not a duplicate. (a) That one is Android, this one is Java. (b) That one is only about text format using offset-from-UTC, while this one asks about the name of a time zone in addition to the offset.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Is your real problem how to convert an old-fashioned `Date` object into a modern `ZonedDateTime`? (There’s no need to go through formatting and parsing for that.)

Answer (score 8):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime                        // Represent a moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). 
.now(                                // Capture the current moment.
    ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" )  // Specify the time zone through whose wall-clock time we want to perceive the current date and time.
)                                    // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toString()                          // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.
```

> 2017-11-23T23:43:45-05:00[America/New_York]

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines many practical formats for representing date-time values as human-readable text. The first chunk of your desired format is one such standard format:

> 2017-11-23T23:43:45-05:00

Your desired format extends standard format by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

> 2017-11-23T23:43:45-05:00[America/New_York]

That extended standard format is exactly the behavior of the [`ZonedDateTime::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toString()) method. You will find that class bundled with Java.

```
ZonedDateTime.now().toString()  // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The `SimpleDateFormat` class is part of the troublesome old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Never use these awful legacy classes.

## `ZonedDateTime`

Get the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Generate a `String` object containing text in your desired format.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;  // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX** to print time as **2017-11-23T23:43:45-05:00** and there is no format specifier for [America/New_York]. You can use [zzzz] which will print as [Eastern Standard Time] not as [America/New_York]

Comment: Ok thank you! And how to I get  [America/New_York] in android?

Comment: @Johnnyboy You use [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) if your Android runs Java 8, or [ThreeTen Android Backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP#threeten-android-backport), if not.

Answer (score 0):

A given offset can map to more than one name, for example UTC-0500 can be `America/New_York` or `America/Toronto` or `America/Montreal` or `America/Nassau` (there are probably more).  More precise geographic information would be needed to choose the correct one, and the "correct one" could depend on other factors as well.

This is why there's no simple API to return this value, there's no canonical right answer.  You will have to decide your own rules for determining the string and then use the TZ database to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

This helps

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ") .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Joda-Time? An option, though most think that its replacement, java.time, is better. Available on (older) Android through [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).