# Android - Converting current date and time with timezone

Tags: java, android, datetime, simpledateformat

How can I convert the current time like this kind of format **2018-09-21T01:56:57.926986+00:00** on android?. I'm using `DateFormat` but I don't know how to add an timezone on it. This is the code that I'm using when getting the current date and time

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                                    Date date = new Date();
                                    String curDate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: see the SimpleDateFormat on Android Developer Guide, plz. you should use the format like "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX".

Comment: thanks mate but "XXX" doesn't work on android studio. But anyways, I find the solution. thanks

Comment: That sounds good, please vote helpful flag, thanks.

Comment: Near-duplicate of [Android Format date with time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157476/android-format-date-with-time-zone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use *java.time* classes.

```
OffsetDateTime            // Represent a moment as a date, a time-of-day, and an offset-from-UTC (a number of hours, minutes, seconds) with a resolution as fine as nanoseconds.
.now(                     // Capture the current moment. 
    ZoneOffset.UTC.       // Specify your desired offset-from-UTC. Here we use an offset of zero, UTC itself, predefined as a constant.
)                         // Returns a `OffsetDateTime` object.
.format(                  // Generate text in a `String` object representing the date-time value of this `OffsetDateTime` object.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSxxxxx" , Locale.US )
)                         // Returns a `String` object.
```

> 2018-09-27T05:39:41.023987+00:00

Or, use `Z` for UTC.

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

> 2018-09-27T05:39:41.023987Z

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* that supplanted the terrible old date-time classes.

Specifically:

- Use `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime` instead of `java.util.Date`.
- Use `DateTimeFormatter` instead of `SimpleDateFormat.

Get the current time in UTC. We use the `OffsetDateTime` class rather than `Instant` for more flexible formatting when generating text.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.UTC;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( offset );
```

Define a formatting pattern to match your desired output. Note that the built-in formatting patterns use `Z` as standard shorthand for `+00:00`. The `Z` means UTC and is pronounced “Zulu”. This Zulu time format is quite common. I suggest using such formats with `Z`. But you asked explicitly for the long version of an offset-from-UTC of zero, so we must use a custom [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSxxxxx" , Locale.US );
String output = odt.format( f );
```

> 2018-09-27T05:39:41.023987+00:00

FYI, the formats discussed here comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).