# Cnvert String to Date in Java

Tags: java

I have the following string in Java:

```
2011-12-21T20:27:32-08:00
```

Can any one tell me how do I store this string by converting it to date?

I need to store it in a MySQL column declared as TimeStamp.

I've tried the following but it does not work:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz").parse("2011-12-21T20:27:32-08:00");
```

It gives below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2011-12-21T20:27:32-08:00" –
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: gives error: Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2011-12-21T20:27:32-08:00"

Comment: @FreephonePanwal I'd update your question to include that, even though it's already been answered, it could help other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), `z` expects timezone indicators in a different format than the one in your string, but you can use `X` instead, which supports them. So (change is at the end of the format string):

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX").parse("2011-12-21T20:27:32-08:00");
```

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Letter  Date or Time Component   Presentation         Examples
------  -----------------------  -------------------  -------------------------------------
z       Time zone                General time zone    Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
Z       Time zone                RFC 822 time zone    -0800
X       Time zone                ISO 8601 time zone   -08; -0800; -08:00
```

---

[Daniel Kaplan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61624/daniel-kaplan) points out in the comments that `X` seems to be new. You might need to pre-process the string a bit to remove the colon and use `Z` (capital, not `z`; the second in the list above) instead, depending on your environment.

Comment: Just be aware `X` is new.  [At least it's not in the documentation of JDK6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I'm not clear. X seems to be working for me. What would be the impact if I deploy my code to production with X?

Comment: @FreephonePanwal What's the version of your JDK and what's the version of your JDK on production?  Type `java -version` to find out. If they're both 1.7 it should be fine.

Comment: They're 1.7 & I should compile with same version i.e. 1.7 as Production before deployment, right?

Comment: @FreephonePanwal: Yup, as long as you're using JDK 1.7+ and the JRE it'll be running on is 1.7+, `X` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this question: [Java SimpleDateFormat for time zone with a colon seperator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375222/java-simpledateformat-for-time-zone-with-a-colon-seperator). The first answer may be helpful.