# Java date format string for date "Wednesday, January 2, 2013 5:29:26 PM +02:00"

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm importing some data into some system and it asks me to provide a java date format string for the dates in my CSV document. I'm not a Java programmer, and I have difficulties of testing it. It asks to use syntax valid for [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

I have dates like this one `Wednesday, January 2, 2013 5:29:26 PM +02:00` and this is the format string I came with based on documentation, however, it fails:

```
EEEE, MMM d, y hh:mm:ss a Z
```

I think the time zone format string is wrong, but I don't know the right solution. Please help.

Comment: The problem is `+02:00`, Java is expecting `+0200`.  If you can correct this, it will parse correctly

Comment: You could also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375222/java-simpledateformat-for-time-zone-with-a-colon-seperator) which discusses your problem and even [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Comment: Yeah, I can replace them in TextMate, timezone should be the same in all records since all data was written from the same place. Thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: @MadProgrammer please post your answer as an answer instead of the comment here, so, I'll be able to vote for it and mark as a correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is +02:00, Java is expecting +0200. If you can correct this, it will parse correctly

Answer (score 0):

Consider Joda Time library, which has built in support for parsing and outputting ISO-format date strings.

Comment: Please read my question. I'm not a Java programmer and it is worthless to learn how to write and execute `Hello SimpleDateFormat` program, this should be very easy question for Java programmer.

Comment: Handling time looks like an easy task to most people but it usually turns out it isn't, i.e. many developers don't understand time zone offsets and universal time.

Answer (score 0):

To debug date parsing errors, print out the date format.

eg:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM d, y hh:mm:ss a Z").format(new Date()));
```

and then adjust until you see the right format.

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, the answer to your problem:

```
C:\Users\Cebence\jdev\StackOverflow> java StackOverflow15914753
input = Wednesday, January 2, 2013 5:29:26 PM +02:00

Parsing input into date ............   [ OK ]

    date @ local = Wed Jan 02 16:29:26 CET 2013
ISO date @ local = 2013-01-02T16:29:26.000+01:00
        UTC date = 2013-01-02T15:29:26.000Z
```

This output was created by the following demo application.
Note the importance of **correct time zone, locale and the "X" instead of "Z"** for parsing.
The "X" handles "+02:00" and will work only on Java 7.

```
    // Important to be US!
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(CUSTOM_FORMAT_WITH_TZ, Locale.US);
    // Important to be +2 hours offset!

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;


/**
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914753/java-date-format-string-for-date-wednesday-january-2-2013-52926-pm-0200
 * input: "Wednesday, January 2, 2013 5:29:26 PM +02:00"
 * asking-for: working timestamp format string "EEEE, MMM d, y hh:mm:ss a Z"
 *
 * @author dejan.cebetarevic
 */
public class StackOverflow15914753 {
  private static final String ISO_FORMAT_WITH_TZ = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX";
  private static final String ISO_FORMAT_NO_TZ = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
  private static final String CUSTOM_FORMAT_WITH_TZ = "EEEE, MMMM d, y hh:mm:ss a XXX";
  private static final String DEFAULT_INPUT = "Wednesday, January 2, 2013 5:29:26 PM +02:00";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Assume default input.
    String input = DEFAULT_INPUT;

    // But if an input was given, use it.
    if (args.length == 1) {
      input = args[0];
    }
    System.out.println("input = " + input);

    System.out.print("\nParsing input into date ............");
    Date d = createCustomDateFormat().parse(input);
    System.out.println("   [ OK ]\n");

    System.out.println("    date @ local = " + d);
    System.out.println("ISO date @ local = " + isoFormat(d));
    System.out.println("        UTC date = " + utcFormat(d));
  }

  public static String utcFormat(Date date) throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat utc = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_FORMAT_WITH_TZ, Locale.UK);
    utc.setCalendar(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));
    return utc.format(date);
  }

  public static String isoFormat(Date date) throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat iso = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_FORMAT_WITH_TZ);
    return iso.format(date);
  }

  public static SimpleDateFormat createCustomDateFormat() throws Exception {
    // Important to be US!
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(CUSTOM_FORMAT_WITH_TZ, Locale.US);
    // Important to be +2 hours offset!
    format.setCalendar(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2")));
    return format;
  }
}
```