# Convert date or calendar type into string format

Tags: java, date, calendar, type-conversion

So, basically I am trying to achieve the following format in a String:

```
2012-06-17T08:00:00.000+01:00
```

I get the original date in a string format which I then parse into different formats.

When I use SimpleDateFormat with the format as (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ), I get the following output:

```
2013-06-17T07:00:00.000+0530
```

Here +0530 should be +05:30

When I set the above date into a Calendar type and then convert it to a string I get the following format:

```
2013-06-17T07:00:00+05:30
```

Here I don't get the .000 after the seconds.

Any ideas how this can be achieved, without using JodaTime. Need manipulations in Date, String and Calendar type only

Comment: Check the Java docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) `s` refers to seconds and `S` to milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly to get the extra `:` use XXX in your formatter like so and use Uppercase `S` to get the milliseconds

```
   SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
```

**UPDATE:** Above doesn't work on 1.6

Yo could try the following however

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") 
{
    public StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo, java.text.FieldPosition pos) 
    {
        StringBuffer toFix = super.format(date, toAppendTo, pos);
        return toFix.insert(toFix.length()-2, ':');
    };
```

See [this post for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375222/java-simpledateformat-for-time-zone-with-a-colon-seperator)

Comment: Thanks, didnt see that part

Comment: getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'X'

Comment: @sanbhat On, 1.6 you're out of luck. It doesn't support ISO 8601 time zone.

Answer (score 0):

*SimpleDateFormat pattern*

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"
```

Comment: On, 1.6 you're out of luck. It doesn't support ISO 8601 time zone.

Comment: Try `zzz` on 1.6 if `GMT-08:00` is fine with you.

Comment: How about the Calendar type, can't we play around with the format there?

Comment: Calendar does not support formatting. It's `toString()` method has a fixed output format that could change between two Java versions. Used for debugging only.

Comment: @Punkeshwar In Joda time you can do it as outlined in this SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2375539/1237040).

Comment: Thapiyal I understand that, just that it is already a very rigid application, in terms of what we can add or use... I think the String manipulation is the only way out, its dirty, but its the one that works....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2012-06-17T08:00:00.000+01:00" )  // Parse string in standard ISO 8601 format to an object.
              .format(                                   // Generate a String representing the value of that `OffsetDateTime` object.
                  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX" )  // Specify a formatting pattern to force the seconds and fractional second even if zero.
              )                                          // Return a `String` object.
```

> 2012-06-17T08:00:00.000+01:00

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes rather than the troublesome old legacy date-time classes. Avoid `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

### ISO 8601

Your desired format happens to be standard ISO 8601 format. The *java.time* classes use the standard format by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

### `OffsetDateTime`

Your input string includes an offset-from-offset but not a time zone. So we parse as a `OffsetDateTime` object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2012-06-17T08:00:00.000+01:00" ) ;
```

To generate a string in the same standard ISO 8601 format, simply call `toString`. By default, the least significant parts are omitted if zero. So no seconds or fractional second appear using your example data.

```
String output = odt.toString() ;
```

> 2012-06-17T08:00+01:00

If you want to force the seconds and fractional second even when zero, specify a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2012-06-17T08:00:00.000+01:00" );
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX" );
String output = odt.format( f );
```

> 2012-06-17T08:00:00.000+01:00

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).