# Correct date formatting for date strings like "2013-11-16T08:46:00.000-06:00"

Tags: java, android, parsing, datetime, simpledateformat

**INPUT:**

```
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

String unformattedDate = "2013-11-16T08:46:00.000-06:00";

String formattedDate = outFormat.format(inFormat.parse(unformattedDate ));
```

**ABOVE OUTPUT:**

```
formattedDate = "2013-11-16T20:16:00.000Z"
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
formattedDate = "2013-11-16T08:46:00.000Z"
```

Can anyone through a light on why is this difference after conversion and how to get the desired output?

I assume that my `inFormat` is not correct to format the date `unformattedDate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like this

```
 String unformattedDate = "2013-11-16T08:46:00.000-06:00";
 Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(unformattedDate);
 String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").format(date);
 System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

**output**

```
2013-11-16T08:46:00.000Z
```

Comment: Great! But how come the second line not giving parse exception as the format of `unformattedDate` is different then "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"  and we are parsing it in second line?

Comment: its because his date format is ignoring the malformatted timezone string. IN the spec the time zone is referenced without a colon `-0600`

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375222/java-simpledateformat-for-time-zone-with-a-colon-seperator