# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "04 Mar 2016 20:33+05:30" (at offset 3)

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mmZ");
date = format.parse("05 Mar 2016 15:37+05:30");
```

is crashing only on some devices eg: (Galay s3 neo GT-I9300I) with

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
"05 Mar 2016 15:37+05:30" (at offset 3)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It should end in `X` and not `Z`.

Comment: Since you're on Android read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375222/java-simpledateformat-for-time-zone-with-a-colon-separator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Z` has no colon separator. You could do

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mmX");
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the SimpleDateFormat docs, `Z/ZZ/ZZZ:-0800`  Notice the colon.  Your string doesn't have one, so parsing it fails.  Yes, its that sensitive.

Comment: funny thing is in many phones, it worked. May be they handled this humanish error :)