# Format ISO 8601 offset in Java

Tags: java, date, time, format, iso

I am trying to get time stamp in this format: **2016-06-07T14:51:15+00:00**

I tried multiple ways as suggested but nothing seems to work. Below are few attempts I made and the outcome.

Trail-1:

```
DatatypeConverter.printDateTime(new GregorianCalendar(Locale.US));
output: 2016-09-29T10:55:12.572-05:00 ( problem: getting milli seconds. I don't want milliseconds )
```

Trail-2:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
output: 2016-09-29T10:56:57-0500 ( problem: offset is missing colon)
```

Trail-3:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
        Date now = new Date();
        String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
 Output: 2016-09-29T10:58:24.764-0500 (problem: offset is missing colon)
```

None of the existing stackoverflow questions on this issue can solve my problem. I am using Java 7. I don't want to use any library like Joda etc..

Comment: I suggest using the JSR-310 library added to Java 8 (with backports for Java 6)

Comment: See [YouEyeK's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22850944/438154) in the duplicate. Use `XXX` in the pattern.

Comment: In windows 7 it gave output as desired but in linux I get this: 2016-09-30T21:42:10Z with xxx solution.