# extending jtextfield value to take date format

Tags: java, swing

I want a text field in java swing which will take only date type of value

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`JFormattedTextField`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) (a subclass of `JTextField`).

The example at [exampledepot.com: Creating a Text Field to Display and Edit a Date](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.text/formtext_FormTextDate.html) should also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

As another instance of @aioobe's suggestion, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241997) uses an [`InputVerifier`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) in conjunction with [`JFormattedTextField`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).