# How to convert string type (java) and store in date data type in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, date

I want to insert valued from JForm to mysql database. But I can't insert values to date field.. This code is working except for date field. Can someone help me..

```
            String s1=txtUsername.getText();
            String s2=txtPassword.getText();
            String s3=txtName.getText();
            String s4=txtAddress.getText();
            String s5=txtContractEndDetails.getText();


            connection getcon = new connection();
            Connection conn;


    try{
        conn=getcon.creatConnection();

             String sql="insert into TravelGuide(username,password,name,address,contract_end_date)values(?,?,?,?,?)";

             PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          java.sql.Date dtValue = java.sql.Date.valueOf(s5); 

           stmt.setString(1, s1);


          stmt.setString(2, s2);

          stmt.setString(3, s3);
           stmt.setString(4, s4);

        stmt.setDate(5, s5);

           stmt.executeUpdate();



        }


    catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(PanelTG, ex.getMessage(),"Error Occured 123",2);
    }
```

Comment: Please post the SQL error message / exception stack trace. Also, what SQL type is the contract_end_date column?

Comment: Yeah.. it's contract_end_date..error message is "Unknown column 'contract_end_date' in 'field list' " ..

Answer (score 0):

In order to turn a string into a `java.util.Date` object, you need a `DateFormat` (e.g. `SimpleDateFormat`)

- [mask the input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037050/extending-jtextfield-value-to-take-date-format) with the desired date format or use a calendar component.
- use `dateFormat.parse(..)` to turn the string into a `Date`.

Comment: the javadoc of `SimpleDateFormat`,  `DateFormat` and `JFormattedTextField` should suffice

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MySQL DB for that you need to Format your s5 variable string to yyyy-mm-dd date. You can format it using dateFormat. Or make sure your s5 variable should contain string like this '2000-06-30'

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). You can parse a `Date` from a `String` using a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Your code could look like this:

```
String s5 = txtContractEndDetails.getText();
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date contractEndDate = null;
try {
     contractEndDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(s5);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // handle telling the user they have bad input
}
stmt.setDate(5, contractEndDate);
```

Notes:

- You'll need to chose a date format suitable for your users. See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info on what options you have
- You need to decide how to handle bad input and code it (either throw an Exception, or show them a message, etc)
- As a matter of style, avoid variable names like `s1`, `s2` etc. They lead to unreadability, and thus bugs: Either use proper names like `name`, `address` etc, or in-line them (ie remove them and directly use the code that initialized them instead)

Comment: Well.. i used java.util.* and java.sql.* they are saying reference to date is ambiguous since both class use the same..

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Date date = new Date();

        DateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String newDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println("DateIn String datatype = "+newDate);

        System.out.println("DateIn Date datatype = "+java.sql.Date.valueOf(newDate));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let Me give u basic go throw how to convert String type data ie we got from Web page/HTML page and the data is been processed in java and then insert it into DB of Mysql.
Below is just a piece of code.

```
        String d = req.getParameter("dob");       
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        java.util.Date convertedDate =  formatter.parse(d);
        java.sql.Date date1 = new java.sql.Date(convertedDate.getTime());
        prestat.setDate(3,  date1);
```