# JFormattedTextField with MaskFormatter

Tags: java, swing, datetime, textfield

I have a `JFormattedTextField` that I use to restrict entries of a date and time. I want to use a `MaskFormatter` though to show the placeholder chars. Is there a way to use a `MaskFormatter` on top of the `JFormattedTextField` when the text field is already using a `SimpleDateFormat`?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
public class MaskFormatterTest {
    private static final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField(df);
        tf.setColumns(20);
        panel.add(tf);
        try {
            MaskFormatter dateMask = new MaskFormatter("####/##/##");
            dateMask.install(tf);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MaskFormatterTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, consider an[`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification), as suggested in [`InputVerificationDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#eg) and this more elaborate [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241997).

Comment: Thanks. I think @I82Much's answer is simpler, but this will also be useful in other situations rather than writing custom focus listeners.

Comment: I agree! My example is a little convoluted, but handy for multiple allowed date formats. +1 to @I82Much, by the way.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @KristerAndersson: Agreed; I've cited more reliable sources, including the vendor sponsored tutorial and an answer on SO itself.

Answer (score -2):

```
JFormattedTextField tft3 = 
    new JFormattedTextField(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    tft3.setValue(new Date());

    Date date = (Date) tft3.getValue();
```

Comment: This doesn't use a masked input field