# how to make a jtextfield having a fixed date format?

Tags: java, swing, date, jtextfield

I'm having trouble creating a fixed date format using `JTextField`.  Is there a way for `JTextField` to have a fixed date format ?

Comment: Have a look at [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).

Comment: Or use a more modern UI component like the [`JXDatePicker`](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t45447.html)

Answer (score 10):

You can use JFormattedTextField with [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("your_format");
JFormattedTextField dateTextField = new JFormattedTextField(format);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at

- [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) (in [particular](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#format) with an [example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.text/formtext_FormTextDate.html) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252257/jformattedtextfield-with-maskformatter))
- [How to use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) (in [particular](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html#standard))

For starters...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Swing, add a JFormattedTextField to your JFrame.  In the Properties, click on formatterFactory.  In the dialog, choose the Date Category and then select a Format.  Now your format will be enforced.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

my solution in Netbeans is : select the date from JDateChooser component ,then one unfocusable jtextfield get the date from the selected date in JDateChooser:
(1)in order to make fixed date format, in the properties of JDateChooser ,for example we set the date format :yyyy-MM-dd ;
(2)make  "jtextfield.setFocusable(false)", this is for avoiding input wrong date format or unwanted characters

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As has been said in the comments, you may prefer to look into a date picker component instead of a text field. A date picker component will save the user from struggling with date syntax.

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. So for anyone preferring a text field for a date, I did a small experiment with using a `JFormattedTextField` in conjunction with the `LocalDate` class from java.time. For the text field I found it nicest to write a little subclass specifying that the type of object we get from a date field is `LocalDate`:

```
public class DateField extends JFormattedTextField {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4070878851012651987L;

    public DateField(DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter) {
        super(dateFormatter.toFormat(LocalDate::from));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 26));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate getValue() {
        return (LocalDate) super.getValue();
    }

}
```

A `JFormattedTextField` accepts a `java.text.Format` object for formatting and parsing values. `DateTimeFormatter` from java.time has a couple of overloaded `toFormat` methods that give us `java.text.Format`. Even one where we can specify the type of object we get from the `Format`.

To try this date field class out:

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame() {
        super("Test");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
                .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("es"));
        DateField dateField = new DateField(dateFormatter);
        add(dateField);
        dateField.setValue(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()));

        JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        okButton.addActionListener(ev -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestFrame.this,
                "Date entered is " + dateField.getValue()));
        add(okButton );

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFrame().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I specified Spanish format just to demonstrate clearly that formatting and parsing is going on. This is where you can specify yourself which format *your* users prefer. For example `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)` or `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uu")`. Consider a short format since most users don’t like typing more than necessary.

Now the `JFrame` came up looking like this:

[image]

Instead of today’s date I entered `11 ago. 2020` and clicked OK:

[image]

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

Use property formatterFactory and select format.[image: like this]

Comment: Where are you finding this formatterFactory? Which tool are you using?

Answer (score -2):

I think the best is using the JFormatedTextField.

I have this code try this one:

```
package your_package;

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class.....{

private String getdate(){
      DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY"); //display your format.
      Date date = new Date();//puts the date in variable.
      return dateformat.format(date); //returns the format to the date variable.
}

public your_app{
     .....
     String date = new getdate();
     txtDate.setvalue(date);
}
}
```

Hope this will give you an idea and helps... :)

Comment: well ... there are some issues with your answer: the code snippet a) doesn't relate to your description b) it won't compile (even with thinking the dots as full-fledged code :-) c) doesn't comply with java naming conventions d) the logic is upside-down (assuming txtData is the formattedTextField) e) nothing new compared to the other answers ...