# How do I use the jFormattedTextfield in Java GUI for entering dates only

Tags: java, swing, date, date-parsing, jformattedtextfield

I am new in Java programming language and I want to constrain the user to input dates in this format pattern only (dd/mm/yyyy). I am using Java Swing controls for drag and drop. please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make a jtextfield having a fixed date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655811/how-to-make-a-jtextfield-having-a-fixed-date-format)

Comment: I warmly recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. Since none of the old answers to the linked original question touched on this, I wrote [a new answer for you here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61446403/5772882).