# Is it possible to turn java.util.Date() to int?

Tags: java, date, integer, long-integer, java.util.date

I am developing an application where I have a `JFormattedTextField` with the current date in `yyyy/mm/dd` format and I want to move to `int` only these values. But the problem and what the eu am doing is returning more values

```java
JFormattedTextField textId = new JFormattedTextField(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"));
textId.setValue(new java.util.Date());
textId.setBounds(20, 310, 100, 25);
Date data = (Date)textId.getValue();
long dataFinal = data.getTime();
```

How can I make the value of the Int only `YYYY/MM/DD`?
With `long`, the variable `dataFinal` at the moment gives `1603883824076` is this the current time in nanoseconds?

Comment: Just format date using SimpleDateFormater as "yyyyMMdd" and parse this to int value.

Comment: Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: I'm fine with doing any reading at all, honestly. To find out *e.g.* about format being milliseconds.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Why do you want an `int`? What is the need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like the following?

```java
JFormattedTextField textId = new JFormattedTextField(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"));
textId.setValue(new java.util.Date());
textId.setBounds(20, 310, 100, 25);
String str = textId.getText().replaceAll("/", "");
int integer = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

The value of `integer` is 20201028 (because today's date is 2020/10/28, i.e. 28<sup>th</sup> October 2020)

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work.
2. If you need an `int`, use a count of days since the epoch day of January 1, 1970.

The two suggestions go nicely hand in hand since java.time offers a `toEpochDay` method for the conversion:

```
    Format localDateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd")
                                .toFormat(LocalDate::from);
    JFormattedTextField textId = new JFormattedTextField(localDateFormat);
    textId.setValue(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
    textId.setBounds(20, 310, 100, 25);
    LocalDate data = (LocalDate) textId.getValue();
    int dataFinal = Math.toIntExact(data.toEpochDay());
```

Today — October 29, 2020 — will give you 18564.

> … with long the variable datefinal at the moment gives 1603883824076
> is this the current time in nanoseconds? …

They are milliseconds since the epoch of January 1, 1970, 00:00 UTC. And as you have probably noticed, they don’t fit into an `int`.

**Links**

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61446403/5772882) to the question *how to make a jtextfield having a fixed date format?* giving more detail on using `LocalDate` with `JFormattedTextField`.

Comment: Very nice explanation!