# Fixed date separators on a textfield (dd-mm-YYYY)

Tags: java, swing, input, calendar, jformattedtextfield

I need a textfield used for a date input, with fixed separators in order to help the user check the date he is writing.
I need it to come as default with "-" separators between date month and year: xx-xx-xxxx, when x is just spaces at the begining, but after the user input something like: 03-05-1992. 
How can i get this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `JFormattedTextField` with `SimpleDateFormat` and `MaskFormatter`, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4252337/2251226).

Comment: or JSpinner with SpinnerDateModel