# Time Formatting in a JtextArea

Tags: java, swing, datetime, time, jtextarea

Is there any library that can check my jtextarea the right input time format?

for example the input format must be *hh:mm:ss* or *hh:mm* only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `JFormattedTextField` with `MaskFormatter`, as shown in this question: [JFormattedTextField with MaskFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252257/jformattedtextfield-with-maskformatter)

Comment: can i use this one?  MaskFormatter dateMask = new MaskFormatter("hh:mm:ss");

Comment: Really it should be something like this: 

    MaskFormatter dateMask = new MaskFormatter("##:##");
    dateMask.install(input);

Comment: the problem here.. its time right what if they input 25:61

Comment: Please, check out this: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-time-in-24-hours-format-with-regular-expression/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want to use a `JTextArea` for this, as it's really designed to allow the user to type free text.

Normally you would use a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and for more [examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

Other options would include the use for a [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) or [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)