# How to change the format of a JFormattedTextField at runtime?

Tags: java, swing

I know you can pass a format to JFormattedTextField constructor, but how would you change the formatter at runtime? For example I have a field that is supposed to be formated to integer values, but when a value of a certain combo box is changed, now the field is supposed to take float values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could invoke [setFormatterFactory(JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatterFactory)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#setFormatterFactory(javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatterFactory)) on your object.

You can use it in this fashion:

```
// Define the number factory.
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(); // Specify specific format here.
NumberFormatter nff = new NumberFormatter(nf);
DefaultFormatterFactory factory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(nff);

// Define the decimal factory.
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(); // And here..
NumberFormatter dnff = new NumberFormatter(df);
DefaultFormatterFactory factory2 = new DefaultFormatterFactory(dnff); 

// Then you set which factory to use.
JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField();
field.setFormatterFactory(factory);
//field.setFormatterFactory(factory2);
```

So just set the factory when your event occurs.

Note that the constructor of `DefaultFormatterFactory` can take several formatters; a default one, a display format when it doesn't have focus, an edit format when it has focus, and a null format for when the field has a null value.

Comment: Have you tried to directly call setFormatter on a JFormattedTextField instance before recommending this?  You do know that it's a protected method, right?

Comment: Missed the fact that setFormatter() is protected.

Comment: @netrom Formatter and Format aren't really the same. Although I can set a formatter factory I don't see how it will change the format of the field. Maybe I am missing something. If you have an example I would really like to see it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it seemed to work, but I really dislike the complexity of the solution. I eventually went with something similar to trashgod's solution.

Comment: @m0s: I agree. Would have done similar myself, thinking about it now. :)

Answer (score 1):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241997) uses `InputVerifier` to add variations to a default format. It's designed for `Date`, but you might be able to adapt the approach to `Number`.