# How to retrieve JFormattedTextField integer value?

Tags: java

The problem is JFormattedTextField automatically changes the Integer to the formatted Integer (Eg: 5000000 to 5,000,000).
With JTextField, I can convert 5000000 to Integer using parseInt(). But how can I do that with JFormattedTextField when it's value is 5,000,000.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the Format classes in java.text:

```
String num = "5,000";
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.###");
try {
    System.out.println(format.parse(num).toString()); // prints 5000
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm watching Java API for JFormattedTextField and I noted that it has a setFormattedFactory(...) method and I think you can use this method to change the format of retrieved values.

Try to follow the answer to this question to use that method : [How to change the format of a JFormattedTextField at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204705/how-to-change-the-format-of-a-jformattedtextfield-at-runtime)

Here instead it's explained how parse a big number with comma : [Convert a String to Double - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097332/convert-a-string-to-number-java)

I hope it's useful for you! bye